# Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, disputed-flags, flag-history

What does it mean when a flag is disputed?  How is that different from being declined?  I don't see a clear explanation for this in my flagging history, so just asking it here.  Ironically, the first explanation I've seen was in the tag description for this post.

It seems like a surprisingly simple question not to be posted elsewhere on this meta.  On that note, I think the explanation for each type of flag would be helpful information to add under "Your flagging history."

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511/186381

Comment: it's two different scenarios. A flag disputed implies that, as Servy's link states - a mod disagrees with flag, and is leaving it hanging. Sometimes it just means the flag is obsolete or no-longer applicable(so just a neutral situation and flag is left alone). Flags declined are denied flags , a mod explicitly rejected flag...

Comment: @Coffee That's not a proper analysis of a disputed flag.

Comment: @Coffee Your edit is *still* wrong.  Disputed flags are never touched by a moderator.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From [an answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511):

> Helpful means a [Moderator] specifically marked the flag as helpful, or the action that you were suggesting through a flag was taken by the community.
>
> Declined means that a [Moderator] specifically declined the flag.
>
> Disputed basically means neither happened. A [Moderator] never actually looked at the flag and declined it, but the action you suggested wasn't taken in response to the flag either. This can happen in any number of cases; certain flags are marked disputed when the post is edited; non-moderator users can choose not to act on a flag (either through the 10k tools page (which has since been removed) or through certain review queues) which disputes a flag, etc...
>
> While having declined flags is bad, having disputed flags is...less so.  They're certainly not something to be *as* concerned about, because it usually means someone wasn't specifically evaluating your flag, but rather performing some related action that rendered your flag "moot" in some way.
>
> Declined flags will "count against you", but disputed flags won't; it's more like you never submitted them in the first place...

Comment: I'd have guessed the words meant the opposite things -- Disputed that a Moderator said Nope! and Declined that the flag just gently faded away, as in "declining health".   ...Too late to change now, though.

Comment: Where would declined flags "count against me"?

Answer (score 38):

Since a lot of questions are marked as a duplicate of this one and there is no explicit answer in this thread:

A flag raised during triage becomes [disputed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree) if the outcome of triage is not [unsalvagable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage). In any case, even if the post is eventually deleted or closed, the flag stays disputed and will not turn helpful even if it was raised correctly during triage.

Comment: Quite a few questions about this topic - finally an answer that makes sense. Having spent some time "working the triage queue" recently, I've had the same thing happen several times. You flag something, say, a question, someone edits that question or eager people vote "should be improved", and the flag automatically gets set to "disputed"... before anyone actually gets around to looking at it. Later, sanity prevails, your flag is proven to be right, but it's too late and you look at your flags and wonder whether you're doing something wrong. This needs to be fixed, if you ask me.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter - Hear! Hear! How is it NOT helpful to flag a [vague one-line answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29977045/1677912), when the author gets around to editing into something useful days later? Is the message that "someone would have eventually noticed it was crap without you flagging it?" This is broken.

Comment: I got my first disputed flag today when I flagged [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30552559/4151918) as 'unclear what you're asking.'  Thanks for the explanation!