# flagged Answer as not an answer, it was disputed and deleted

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[Sql Server string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207190/sql-server-string-to-date-conversion/207221#207221)

I can't actually see the answer anymore because I don't have the Reputation here to see that kind of stuff.

It was a thought that the OP had and posted as an answer, but it didn't solve the problem that the OP asked about in the question, so I flagged as not an answer.

Is that not a circumstance when I should flag as "Not an answer"?

[image: Flag Disputed?]

Comment: I would venture to say that most flagged answers that start out, "To answer my immediate problem, this seems to work:" then show code are going to be disputed. It *looks* like an answer **and** says it solved the problem. There are tons of posts on here about NaA. But I'm a bit surprised it was deleted with it being so old and so many upvotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your flag went into the [Low Quality Review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5460519) and the result of the review was *Looks OK × 3*.  This review disputed your flag because the community disagreed with your initial flag.

It appears that a moderator reviewed this answer **after your flag** was processed and felt that it wasn't an answer so they deleted it.

For clarification, a *disputed flag* comes from the community not a moderator.

Comment: so I lost an accepted flag to the community, but it's not a declined flag?

Comment: @Malachi disputed means the community aka reviewers disagreed with your flag, declined means a moderator handled your flag.  I'd suggest reading -- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-accepted-declined-flags

Comment: so it still looks like I don't know what to flag? disputed is still a dirty mark like the declined?

Comment: @Malachi Disputed flags don't carry the same weight as a declined flag.