# Yet another question about an off-topic flag

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596590/how-can-i-get-the-current-network-interface-throughput-statistics-on-linux-unix) as "off-topic", and my flag was declined. This is clearly a Linux-related question that has nothing to do with programming, yet, when I flagged it as "off-topic", the flag was declined.

Can someone help me understand why this is? Thanks.

Comment: Old questions with a lot of views and votes tend to be treated differently, especially if the off-topic criteria have changed since the question was asked. Given how popular that question is, the mod probably decided that it was doing enough good for people to forgive the fact that it's now off topic here.

Comment: The off-topic flag has multiple sub-choices, which did you pick?

Comment: @ChrisHayes highly unlike a single moderator actually touched his flag.  If flagged correctly, the community would have reviewed it, not a moderator, and it would have been the action of multiple users in the review queue saying they didn't think the question should be closed.

Comment: Can confirm, this was a flag for closure, not a moderator flag.

Comment: Post is from 2009, back then things were a little different. Don't worry about these old posts so much as new ones being posted. While it is about linux, it is also about what commands can be used to observe network activity. Look at the answers provided, there is plenty of code in them.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fair enough - I always forget which flags go to mods and which ones lead to queues. I suspect the reasoning is the same in this case, though. A lot of reviewers would see the question at 40+ votes and not even consider accepting the close flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it is worth, someone did agree with your flag as the question did pick up a single close vote.  But your flag was likely declined because 3 users in the review queue felt it was on-topic and clicked "Leave Open" before any of the reviewers voted to close the question ([[source]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac/105395#105395)).  We can't tell you exactly why it was declined, simply because we can't get into the heads of every reviewer and know why they clicked leave open.

---

That being said, I can certainly take a guess.

The key sentence from that question is *"How can I return that information at the command line on Linux/UNIX?"*

The command line interface can effectively be scripted and scripting languages are on-topic.  This question falls into a gray area and an area of overlap between Stack Overflow and the computer hardware/software sites (Super User, Linux/Unix, and Ask Ubuntu).  The fact that a question may be **better** on a specific site does not immediately make it off-topic on another.

So given the fact that scripting languages are on-topic, and there is a scripting component to answering that question, then question is on-topic and that is why your flag was declined.

Comment: for the sake of precision, if question dropped off the close queue, flag status would have been "disputed", it requires moderator involvement for it to be "declined" (though I can't tell what status is for asker's flag, they may not be aware of the [difference in these terms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-accepted-declined-flags "Disputed vs. accepted/declined flags") and use them interchangeably)

Comment: @gnat quoting from [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac/105395#105395) *"If your flag was a recommend closure flag, if it receives three "do not close" responses in the Close Votes queue without a single close vote, it will be declined. When you flagged, this is what happened, but later others decided that the question was worthy of closure and therefore closed it."*

Comment: @gnat however, I was intentionally vague because I didn't remember the exact design.  I will revise to include more specifics

Comment: I see, thanks! this way, declined is possible indeed. TIL

Comment: The topicality of the question is indeed a gray area, but I don't think it should stay open. While you _can_ interpret it as "I need a bash/awk script to do X", most people _do_ interpret it as "recommend me a tool" or at best "where can I find that info" (which is arguably more of a unix/linux question). Looking at the answers, 4 out of 16 are scripts, the other 12 are recommendations which tool / proc node to use - potentially useful but not a good fit for SO. And all the recommendation noise hides the more useful and on-topic scripting answers.

Comment: @l4mpi I am providing a reason **why** the flag was declined, not my personal view on the question.  However to address your points, asking for tools is off-topic, but there is not a request for a tool in that question.  Recommending a tool is not a problem either, as long as the answer meets the community guidelines.  For the ones that don't then vote or flag as appropriate.  Loosely interpreting the "tool recommendation" to close questions that don't asking specifically for tools is only going to cause confusion so we shouldn't abuse it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that's why I didn't use the tool recommendation reason. Still, the question is attracting bad answers (there is just one script answer between the accepted answer and the top 5 by votes) and there doesn't seem to be much new information that could be added to it, except for tools that are not yet listed in an answer; thus closing it seems more beneficial than leading it open and providing yet another broken window. And IMO almost all of the existing recommendation answers are rather low-quality, following the "use [name] [link] \n [example commandline invocation]" scheme.

Comment: @l4mpi It should be locked and not closed in that case. Closing implies it's in violation of the rules; in this case it's just an unfortunate magnet for bad answers, but the question itself is okay.

Comment: @ChrisHayes feel free to flag it for being locked, in my experience this will usually be declined. The pragmatic solution is thus to just close the question.