# What makes a flag helpful?

Tags: support, flags, triage

I understand that "helpful" is intended to indicate that a flag was correct or useful, but when helpful flags do not lead to moderator action it is unclear what exactly the helpful criteria are.

I have read from various other posts that at certain times all flags on a post are *automatically* marked helpful, and of course that *moderators taking action* based on flags will mark them as helpful.

What is the full set of criteria that mark flags "helpful"?

---

[The question on disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags) doesn't answer my question here because its tangential explanation of helpful

> the action that you were suggesting through a flag was taken by the community

doesn't explain how some flags (especially many "Unclear what you're asking" flags I've put on poor-quality Triage questions) are marked helpful despite there being seemingly no action taken.

I'm ultimately asking because I'm not sure that these flags are actually helping, or whether some automatic system is marking them helpful even though they did little.

This may be symptomatic of the "4th option" problem in Triage people have discussed, where the question needs improvement but only the author can do so and it's not bad enough to close.

Comment: Are you referring to custom moderator flags only, or any flag type?

Comment: @BoltClock Any flag type. I've seen scattered reports about "in queue X, if action Y is taken, Z flags are marked helpful," but there doesn't seem to be any place where all these conditions can be seen together.

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate; edited.