# How flag gets status "helpful", "disputed" or "declined"?

Tags: discussion, flags

I found one similar question, but it is still not answered ([What makes a flag helpful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287584/what-makes-a-flag-helpful)).

Yesterday I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29582414/creating-index-in-oracle-is-only-for-unique-columns-or-any-type-both-unique-an) as `unclear what you're asking`. Now my flag has status `disputed`, and question is now `put on hold as unclear what you're asking`. If so, why my flag have no status `helpful`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flags get the status "helpful" if either a moderator approves them, or the community agrees by consensus in the review queue to take the action recommended. If the community does not agree with your recommended action, it will be marked "disputed," and if a moderator does not agree it will be marked "declined."

<strike>In this specific case, the community disagreed with your flag in the review queue, so it was initially disputed. Eight hours later the post was edited, then four hours after that it was finally closed.</strike>

Actually, after finding the [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7655436), I think Matt's (now deleted) comment was correct. Your post wasn't disputed first (as the flag history seemed to indicate). It looks like the edit was what triggered the dispute. In either case, a disputed flag doesn't count against you.

Comment: Isn't there the possibility of the community declining a flag, if (nearly) all decline?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure. It's hard for me to keep up with all the nuances of /review.