# Why was this 'not an answer' flag disputed?

Tags: feature-request, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I was reluctant to write another "why was this  disputed" question, but I really think this one is a mistake, and I'd like to understand what happened with it. I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19514541/429427) as NaA, but it was disputed:

[image: Disputed Not an Answer]

The answer was even previously edited by a moderator to remove an unnecessary exclamation and signature, but I believe *all* the content is unnecessary (it's more of a general complaint, offering no answer/solution to any problem).

I have seen the answer [Disputed vs. accepted/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253117/429427) explaining the possible reasons for the dispute, but it doesn't appear that the answer was edited since the flag, leading me to believe that it might have been voted on and people decided that it looks OK. The answer has garnered some upvotes, perhaps because people like to rally round a complaint, and I sincerely hope that this didn't hit a review queue where people lazily thought "Well, it has upvotes, so it must be useful to the community" without actually considering the content of the flagged answer. The fact is it is pushing more useful *real* answers further down the page, making them harder to find.

I would like it if there was a way to see the underlying reason for a disputed flag, if only for users with 10k mod tool access (if there's actually an easy way to do this already for a particular question, I'd like to know!).

Comment: I agree it is useless answer but NAA flags are not meant for useless answers, that is where downvotes are for. If the answer would have ranted about Windows Phone OS it wouldn't be an answer. FYI: I'm not saying I agree with this interpretation of NAA but at least it relieved me from having disputed/declined flags. With some more downvotes and the help of  20K-ers we can delete it....which seems to be the best option.

Comment: It is disputed when another SO user reviews the same post and disagrees with your flag.  They don't leave a detailed trail *why* they disagree so trying to guess at his motivation is but an idle waste of time.  Nevertheless, judging from the screenshot there were at least 5 other SO users that appear to disagree with you so it isn't exactly a completely mystery.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not looking for a detailed explanation as to why each reviewer disagreed (I'm happy to speculate), but rather an indication of what path the flag took. The meta answer I linked indicates that disputes "can happen in any number of cases", and I'd be interested to see what happened after flagging. Also, I don't think the upvoting users disagree that it's NaA, more they are incorrectly using the upvote button in place of a "Right on!" button. I'd argue that in cases like this, moderator intervention is helpful to ensure SE stands by its question/answer site philosophy.

Comment: As you surmised, it was disputed [through the review process](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7341520) by a few "Looks OK" votes. I'm not sure if 10k users have direct access to reviews that a post was subjected to, or if only moderators have such access. It's not clear to me why the moderator who edited the answer left it there either - I would have deleted it, as it seems pretty obvious that it's just an offhand complaint.

Comment: NAA flags are reviewed by other SO users, not moderators.  If you want a mod to look at it then you need to use a custom flag.  Keep in mind that the odds that you'll find him willing to destroy a post with 5 upvotes are rather slim.  Mods are exception handlers, not philosophers.  The best way to deal with an answer that you absolutely hate is to post a better one.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I wasn't aware that NaA flags went straight to non-mods, I'll bear that in mind. I suppose I'd still contend that this _is_ an exception, and that upvotes != confirmation of answer (they ought to be, but I suppose you can't expect 100% of users to vote objectively and for the right reasons).

Comment: @BoltClock That review summary you linked is what I'm looking for, thanks. As you suggested, I'm not sure if I can find it for specific questions myself or if I have to rely on a moderator to find it for me.

Comment: The answer has now been deleted via the meta effect after being downvoted into negative territory. One difference between this and being deleted via the original flag is that the score of the answer is now no longer above +3 so the rep gained is removed.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I thought rep gain was left behind on sufficiently *old* posts when deleted, not sufficiently *upvoted*. Do you have a more thorough explanation you could link to?

Comment: @NathanTuggy "if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,

A score of 3 or greater
Visible on the site for at least 60 days" http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/

Comment: Looks like its been deleted. Meta-effect for the win, once again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I do agree that we *should* be using the NAA flag with the simple definition of "when there is no *attempt* of an answer".

In this case, the "answer" is just an opinion of Apple and their decisions and in no way returns any information back which could be defined as answering the question.
It's more stating why the question OP had to ask their question, rather than answering the question itself.

But, referring to what is likely an official stand point:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/230506

You used the NAA incorrectly in this case as it doesn't conform to the list of "When should I use this flag?".

The NAA flag is to be used for *specific reasons* (as per RobertHarvey's answer).

---

However, the description when raising the flag describes *exactly* what you used it for:

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not attempt to answer the
>   question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another
>   question, or deleted altogether.

So, those specific reasons in RobertHarvey's list should also include the reasons the flag description has.

Or they should change the description to match the bullet point list, and/or change the name of the flag itself, so it doesn't say "not an answer" which people quite logically use when it's "not an answer", like your case here.

Comment: That sounds like a fair analysis of the situation. I agree that some clarification is needed either on the inline flag description or in the official rules. I guess that a majority of flagging users will not be au fait with the rules as described in answers on meta, so I'd expect situations like this to continue to arise until the inconsistency is resolved.

Comment: It's not that the NAA flag was used nonconformantly - but that you can't rely on its outcome if you use it on a post that doesn't fall under that criteria. Sure, the post fits the description of NAA, but you will have a much better chance at eliciting an appropriate response from the right people if you used a custom flag.

Comment: That being said I absolutely have to question why at least two users with domain experience in iOS dev would think that answer looks OK - you don't even need domain knowledge to tell that a complaint is a complaint and not an answer to a question.

Comment: @BoltClock Exactly. Even given the ambiguity of the accepted usage of the NAA, reviewers of that particular instance can see it has no attempt to answer - ie it's not a "wrong" or "partial" answer, there just is no answer. But meh, such is community sometimes.