# Flagged as Too Broad and got flag disputed on a deleted question

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, disputed-flags, needs-more-focus

Today when I was reviewing Triage, I saw a poor question which I think couldn't be improved or at least it should be closed until OP's edit it as the question statement was too broad to answer.

So I reviewed it as Unsalvageable and flagged it as too broad to close the question as you can see in the below image of Triage review history.

[image]

I got flag disputed in return but the question was deleted immediately when I got it.

Review history of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426554/is-there-option-to-test-and-print-the-result-in-xls-test-case-format-in-selenium).

[image]

So the point to ponder for me is, did I reviewed it wrongly and got a disputed flag in return or if the question was really poor and it needs to be deleted then why my flag was disputed?

[image]

Comment: For reference, the question was deleted by its owner.

Comment: Maybe the deletion somehow automatically invalidated those flags.

Comment: But the point is it was reviewed and none of the reviewer reviewed it as a good question.

Comment: The question was too broad to answer. Answering it will takes a lot of code but it's not going to be a good answer as it will only be possible answers to a broad question range

Comment: The owner of the post deleted the post. What I meant is that maybe, _that_ action performed by the OP, invalidated any flags existing on the post.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe you are right but if it is happened then flags shouldn't be disputed. As if OP deletes the question, all the flags from all the users should be marked as helpful I guess.

Comment: @Joker: even if the flag reason is incorrect? Automatically invalidating them all is the safer action. This is, assuming my guess that's what's happening, is correct.

Comment: @Cerbrus you made a good point in the above comment but there should be some sort of algorithm to deal with this kind of scenario. Or at least I want to know what is actually happened behind all of this.

Comment: AFAIK, "disputed" does not come with any sort of penalty.  There probably isn't any reason for the system to be concerned about possible false positives.

Comment: It's a not a penalty, but there are badges for helpful flags, and disputed flags don't count towards them.

Comment: @Harry Johnson. If it is then it's good. I only have 6 disputed flags out of 700+ flags.

Comment: @Austin yeah I know about badges for helpful flags. But I'm glad if there is no penalty on disputed flags.

Comment: @Joker there is no penalty indeed, see [Disputed vs. accepted/declined flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253112/839601)

Comment: @gnat It means Moderators has nothing to do with the disputed flags. They are a result of actions performed on that particular post. And also it is not the reason to worry about.

Comment: agree that it's better to learn from disputed flags, even though these are painless. I for one regularly check my [meta-tag:flag-history] for these and I'd start to worry if it was that many of my flags are in disagreement with what other users think

Comment: @gnat I also check my flag history daily and that's why sometimes when I look on the list of flagged post and see unusual responses other than moderator it leaves me in pain. But now at least I am satisfied with your comments and Pizza's answer.

Comment: "I also check my flag history daily" -- this is about 99,99% guarantee that you're doing things right. To expect self flagging correctly "by heart" would be rather slippery; to study _feedback_ on your flags is much more reliable way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason your flag was disputed has nothing to do with the eventual fate of the post. The flags associated with *Unsalvageable* choice are marked disputed immediately if the outcome of Triage is **not** *Unsalvageable*. This is shown on the [flowchart of question lifecycle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288385/hiq-very-low-quality-link/288387#288387).

In your case, the majority of reviewers went with *Should Be Improved*. Don't take it as a sign that you were wrong:   many reviewers currently overuse *Should Be Improved* button (and underuse  *Unsalvageable*). Getting a bunch of disputed flags on your flag summary page is a bit unpleasant, but such is the price of being the voice of reason. As others said in comments, *disputed* is a neutral mark; it carries no negative consequences for you.