# Are raised flags during triage disputed if others disagree?

Tags: support, triage, disputed-flags

Today I performed the following triage review during which I flagged the question (being under 3,000 reputation points) as unsalvageable with the reason of opinion based. I noticed my flag was disputed within fifteen minutes or so and that was probably around the time the review was completed:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7578214

While having a disputed flag is not particularly tragic, and it was closed anyway, in my experience it's very unusual on Stack Overflow to have a disputed status on close flags because of the length of the queue, especially so quickly. I wondered whether it was disputed because I was the only one to mark it unsalvageable?

Without 10,000 reputations points on Stack Overflow I couldn't view the close queue history, but at the time it seemed pretty quiet, and I could only see one close reviewer who was shown as active in the past hour, although that may have just been caching. Anyway it's not particularly important, but I'd be interested to know what caused the disputed status and generally how that side of the triage queue works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your flag was disputed at `2015-04-05 05:37:25Z`, exactly the same moment that the review completed, so it does look like the review process is what triggered the dispute. For what it's worth, I don't think that question is salvageable either. No amount of improvement is going to make "is this book still relevant" on-topic for Stack Overflow, so I think your choice was the correct one.

Comment: Huh. I guess that explains where most of my disputed flags are coming from then. Any poor bloke that frequently flags dupes in Triage must really get the short end of the stick there.

Comment: For the record [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) is the official flow chart proving your point.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: indeed. As posted [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293611/983430) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/983430), something needs to be changed...