# Is flagging dupes in Triage mostly useless, completely useless, or worse than useless?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions, triage, disputed-flags

Per [this mod-answered meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree), it seems that Triage flags are quite prone to getting disputed *when Triage resolves*, without necessarily making it beyond. That's bad enough, but what I'm wondering is this: given that duplicates are usually substantially less obvious than most other close reasons (except in some trivial cases where they're almost as easy as Unclear or Too Broad), and therefore that consensus is harder to build on them, and given further that dupe flags will go nowhere unless the consensus is that it should be closed (and perhaps even that it is, in fact, a dupe)… should we just flat-out never flag as dupe in Triage?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not a lot of folks raise duplicate flags in Triage; as you say, it's time-consuming. Triage wasn't really designed for this, so there's not really much extra support for dup-hunting there I'm afraid - you don't even get the handy "related" sidebar you see on normal questions.

The "helpful" rate for duplicate flags in Triage over the past couple of weeks is a bit over 50%, which is less than the site-wide 60% helpful rate for such flags. However... 81% of those questions actually got closed, and only 48% got answered *before* being closed - compare that to 73% closed and 57% answered for dup-flags as a whole.

Right now, I'd say only bother dup-flagging if you see a question that you *know* is a duplicate without hunting. In that scenario, you aren't going to waste much time and have a pretty solid chance of getting the question closed before anyone wastes time answering. If you gotta go hunt for it, it's probably not worthwhile.

Comment: `a question that you know is a duplicate without hunting` [There's an entire tag filled with such questions!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullpointerexception)

Comment: Yup. Some real no-brainers there.