# Duplicate flags shouldn't be disputed on a question that "Looks OK"

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions, triage

When the consensus on a question in [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) is that the question <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>, **all** flags on it are disputed ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjvml.png)).

This makes sense for off-topic/unclear/broad/opinion-based/VLQ flags, but not for duplicate flags. Closing a question as a duplicate doesn't necessarily indicate that the question is unfit for the site - all it indicates is that it's been asked and answered before.

Therefore, **stating that a question "Looks OK" shouldn't dispute duplicate flags.**

Comment: I think the idea is that if you're saying it "Looks OK" you're saying that the question doesn't need to be closed *at all*.

Comment: @BSMP "**Looks OK** for questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is"

Comment: Agreed here. There are many subjects that a triage reviewer can make an on-topic/off-topic decision but CAN'T know if the question is a duplicate, even a well-known dupe to someone who's active in the relevant tag.

Comment: @Siguza If you click on "Unsalvageable" one of the options is marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290533/is-flagging-dupes-in-triage-mostly-useless-completely-useless-or-worse-than-us

Comment: @BSMP appeal to status quo isn't really a convincing argument. It's foolish to expect a triage reviewer to know whether a question is a duplicate in a tag they may have little to no experience with. "Looks OK" should not dispute duplicate flags, full stop.

Comment: @AdamSmith I wasn't making an argument. I don't understand why you're trying to pick a fight with me.

Comment: If a triage reviewer has little to no experience with what they're looking at, shouldn't they choose "skip" instead of "looks ok"?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Lots of times you can know whether a question is good or bad without having no knowledge about the tag. Knowing if it's a duplicate is much more difficult, even if you are an expert in that language.

Comment: @Oriol I mostly agree with you, but I think without specific knowledge of the content, I think it's much easier to know that a question is bad than it is to know if it's good.

Comment: eh, it's just as easy to mistake a good question as a bad one. I wouldn't want to restrict this based on badge progress. Not canceling dupe close votes/flags and leaving the rest should be good nuf