# Is commenting your action in triage appropriate?

Tags: discussion, triage

I'm having a lot of disputed flags because I followed the advice in [Suggestion for rewording of triage review guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance/290915#290915) which is that questions which are not salvagable by other users (but only by the author) are, well, <kbd>Unsalvagable</kbd> and need to be flagged. Other reviewers do not agree with that and hit <kbd>Should Be Improved</kbd> such as recently in  https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7815331

I thought about commenting my triage actions (such as the reason why I am flagging and how I am flagging) in order to educate and influence other reviewers. (The last part is worded intentionally provocative, but you get the point).

I'm unsure if this is appropriate, I've seen people do it for close votes.

Comment: No, if the outcome of the triage is Needs improvement, all flags raised in triage are disputed. I don't have the link at hand, but I've checked that recently, @ArtjomB.

Comment: You're right: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289386/are-raised-flags-during-triage-disputed-if-others-disagree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would support this approach in case the flagged posts are hard to judge, or more than one categorization for flagging seems appropriate. In the best case, it would produce a discussion and would (hopefully) attract the OP's attention. Furthermore, adequate reasoning for the flags could produce rather positive effect to the OP and help him/her adapt to the site rules better.

Maybe the OP could make necessary edits to the post so that either he removes the need of flagging, or confirm any doubts the post deserves a particular flag. This could also fit nicely with the capability of the other users who have flagged to change their flag preference (or remove the flag).

After all, I feel that flagging and discussing over it is as essential as the other Wiki principles embodied in the SE network.