# Please let us re-flag disputed Triage questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, triage, disputed-flags

When you flag a question from the Triage review queue by marking it Unsalvageable, if the question is not ultimately found to be Unsalvageable then [your flag will automatically be disputed & cleared](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289386/1175868).

In *theory* that sounds great; if the question is in fact OK (or can be made OK) then those flags *should* be cleared. The problem is that lately we seem to have a lot of Triage reviewers who are [marking things as Should Be Improved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289658/1175868) when the question is actually trash that ends up getting closed later on.

If a question gets sent to Help & Improvement from Triage, can we either:

1. not clear any flags it received during Triage, or
2. allow users who flagged it during Triage to flag it again after their Triage flag gets disputed?

Addendum: To avoid wasting my flags, I started opening questions I wanted to flag in a new window and flagging them normally rather than from the Triage queue... but my flags are still getting disputed. At the very least can flags that weren't cast through the Triage queue not be immediately disputed if the question is sent to Help & Improvement?

Comment: +1. I've made an [alternative suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293611/983430) to the same underlying issue.

Comment: Re: avoiding wasting flags, what about opening the question in a new window, waiting until it finishes triage review, and _then_ flagging it?