# Auto-convert disputed flags when they prove to be correct

Tags: feature-request, flags, triage, disputed-flags

Having participated in clearing the Triage queues recently, I've found more and more that some of my flags end up being disputed. My first thought was that, just as people can disagree about votes on Triage posts, people higher up can disagree about whether or not my flag was accurate. Fair enough. But, in several cases, questions I flagged as "off topic" ended up getting closed as "off topic". So I read up a bit and was astounded at the number of meta questions asking, "Why was my flag disputed?"

[image: Related questions about disputed flags]

No, this is not another of those questions. This is a suggestion. Because after learning about it, I discovered that pending flags get converted to "disputed" automatically based on certain rules. I won't go into those rules here (sometimes I think it gets tricky, because at the time the flag is made, it's based on the first version, while others vote that it's salvageable based on an edited version), but I'd like to make a suggestion:

**When *disputed* flags ultimately turn out to have been correct all along, can we not convert them to *helpful*?**

Obvious example: User flags question as off-topic, flag becomes disputed, later, question is marked as off-topic. System marks flag as helpful. No moderator input required. Less confusion ensues.

Not so much because having disputed flags is such a bad thing (I've read that it isn't, it's just a by-product of how the system works), but because it will stop the confusion and the flood of related questions here on meta.

**Edit**: After reading through some good comments and thinking about the underlying issue a bit more, I'm starting to think that the question mentioned in @AJPerez's comment is more closely related than I initially thought. Just now, looking at the triage queue, I knew an answer wasn't good as it was, and trying to decide between "should be improved" and "unsalvageable", it seemed that the former was just... the *safer, easier choice*. It's less effort (just a click as opposed to finding my path to the best-fitting flag, which isn't always a clear decision), and the lurking feeling that others will just take the easy choice and mark it "should be improved" means that, if I flag it, chances are that my flag will automatically become "disputed" anyway. I suspect that, like me, many others looking at triage queues want to do the right thing and learn the ropes as well, but having your opinion be "disputed" when you think you're doing the right thing is always a little bit of a setback.

My above suggestion may not be the best option, but it seems clear to me that *something* should be done about it. I like @BenVoigt's idea of renaming "disputed" to "no consensus". I also think the word "unsalvageable" as well as the description that a question "cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site" is inaccurate, because some of the flags are there to tell the OP to read up on how to ask or how to create a MCVE, etc., so the questions aren't "unsalvageable", they just *need more work*. Note how that sounds like *should be improved*... it's hard to learn the ropes when lines are so blurry.

Comment: This seems a nice idea but if its only to stop the meta-posts we might as well have a feature request to disable the down-vote button on main. All joking over: if this gets implemented shouldn't it be also be the other way around? There doesn't seem to be an end state of your flags in this case. They can flip from helpful to disputed and back for the lifetime of the site.

Comment: @rene: huh? I didn't say anything about them flipping, or needing an "end-state". Just converting from disputed - which, I think, shouldn't be an end-state, ideally (though of course that'd be a nightmare in practice on SO) - to helpful if and only if the question gets closed for the same reason it was flagged in the first place. I'd even leave it in that state if the question is re-opened (because circumstances may well have changed, e.g. edits to improve/clarify the question). And of course the "only to stop the meta questions" bit was written with my tongue firmly in my cheek.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that this is trying to re-write history only to get the helpful flag rate up for a user. I'm missing the link between a post gets flagged in a certain timeframe, non-consensus is reached, hence a disputed flag, then some time later a new barrage of flags and votes are raised on the post and then that outcome all of a sudden validates your earlier flag. The outcome might be the same, the road to that outcome is different. I see those outcomes as different and unrelated events.

Comment: I find it *extremely* annoying when one of my flags gets disputed because of the Triage queue. I hate it. However, I'd prefer to fix the actual problem, [the "Should be improved" vs "Unsalvageable" thing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293463/112934), rather than go messing with the flag statuses...

Comment: Rather than seeing it as though it's "only to get the helpful flag rate up for a user", I see it as "getting the discouraging disputed flag rate down for a user"; clearly, many people don't understand the reason behind it (and it's not obvious). What I'm still trying to figure out is which one of us is the glass-half-empty-guy...

Comment: @AJPerez: Good point, and I agree that should be fixed as well. But isn't that issue mostly about the "should be improved" category? I'm not sure how fixing it would solve the problem of having flags marked (and stay marked) as "disputed", which sounds quite negative, just because someone edited a question, for instance.

Comment: @Amos: If the goal is to cure "the discouraging disputed flag rate", then what about renaming from *disputed* to *no consensus*?  That should make it less discouraging.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Also a good point. That would probably go a long way to clearing up the confusion. That name would be a lot more accurate, I think.

Comment: Look, I get that my suggestion isn't perfect and has holes. It just seems that... _something_... needs to be done to fix this, and it's the best I could come up with. And I thought, since some mechanics seem to already be in place to automagically set flags one way, it shouldn't be too tricky to set conditions for them to be set another way.

Comment: I have also some disputed flags which on postings which where deleted later. Those flags should been helpful too.

Comment: @rene I do think the cause of this is separate from the desire to see flags marked as helpful, but there *are* instances outside of the queue (just flagging stuff in general on the site) where I will flag stuff, say for a moderator, and it gets marked declined, but whatever I flagged gets closed/deleted/dealt with anyway within minutes/hours. *That* is annoying to me. But it's tough to determine *when* or *how* our flags were helpful because there's no transparency to the process. We can't see *who* responded to our flag to follow along; we just accept that "someone" found it helpful or not.

Comment: I stopped flagging vlq when these two were declined: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219141/how-to-create-a-calculator-for-gamehostingjs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218945/google-script-cut-and-paste-row in a row

Comment: This makes total sense to me - it's just plain logical that if you cast a flag and the action that the flag indicates is indeed taken by mods or by the community, that that flag should be marked helpful, regardless of whether *one or two* other people "disputed" it.  I think the problem it fixes isn't even the "discouragement" of disputed flags, but moreso the *feedback* a reviewer gets - if your actual good flags are consistently marked as not helpful, you may think you're doing something wrong when you're not.  This happens too much in the Triage queue to ignore.

Comment: Er .... apologies, I meant the feedback the flagger gets.

Comment: I agree, @Ajean, that getting the right feedback is important, but it's not just about _people_ disputing flags. It's the _automated_ transition to disputed when anyone edits the post that I think is not well thought out. I suppose the logic behind it is that if someone edits it, it must be worthy of salvaging, so the flags from people considering it "unsalvageable" (which I consider to be an inaccurate word, as I said) must be wrong. So we have people flagging poorly written posts in conflict with people editing poorly written posts - when they should all be rowing in the same direction.

Comment: Yeah… I flagged http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309142 as off-topic → “lacks MCVE”, flag got disputed but now it’s on hold for exactly that reason… Is there any recent progress on this?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Is there a way to deal with this or not?

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski: There are several ways to deal with this, the easiest (and current) being to ignore when it happens. I made one possible suggestion in my post (90 upvotes to date seem to indicate that others are frustrated with the status quo as well) of what else could be done - feel free to add your own as an answer. :-)