# What to do about my disputed flags?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I don't fully understanding Disputed flags. I understand they are like "nothing happened", and they don't count as much against me as declined. But that is not what worries me.
*I think disputed flags are potentially wasting good efforts for cleaning up the site from bad/incorrect posts.*

I understand an edit can dispute a flag, but if that is the case, why does the OP appear as the one disputing my flag instead of the person making the edit?

Also, **can users dispute flags placed upon their post?** Does an option for doing such appear for them? Because I have seen disputed flags on posts that had no edits and I would guess if a user with high rep disputed my flag he/she would appear as the disputer.

My following flags appear as **disputed** by the OPs that posted them:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30430971/i-am-not-getting-the-css-file-in-my-ruby-project-output : flagged as **Unclear what you are asking**
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250836/calling-webservice-using-javascript: flagged as **Too broad**
- [SQLPlus - spooling to multiple files from PL/SQL blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630068/sqlplus-spooling-to-multiple-files-from-pl-sql-blocks/10488190#10488190): flagged as **Not an answer**
- [Cassandra java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656131/cassandra-java-client): flagged as **Off-topic**

I had some other disputed flags but those questions were closed/deleted so that has been dealt with.

By [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag):

> Disputed flags are considered neither helpful nor declined, regardless
>   of the action taken in response to them.

**So, what should we do about disputed flags? Would it be ok to re-flag?**

Finally, you may arguee the total correctness of my flags, but I think at the very least [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250836/calling-webservice-using-javascript) is not a good question for SO and should be closed.

Comment: It's interesting to compare the tag summaries on SE vs SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disputed-flags and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-flags  The SO one makes sense; the SE one is badly misleading (in my opinion).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"[A]ppear as disputed by the OPs that posted them" is an incorrect interpretation. The flag summary page gives no indication of whose action led to the flag being disputed. (There is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246516/259867) to change this.) Most of the time, it's the collective action of other reviewers who happened to disagree with you — which does not necessarily mean that you were wrong.

You will not be able to raise a close flag after an earlier one was disputed. You can re-flag if an earlier close flag expired without review, but nowadays this is relatively less common.

Comment: I can't believe I have been so blind! You are right, I have made an incorrect interpretation about who disputed the flags. So I guess we are left with downvoting and maybe adding a comment?

Comment: Yes, that and maybe bringing the question to attention of a relevant chat room.

Comment: I think if the flags got disputed automatically by an edit you should be able to re-flag.

Comment: Wait, flags can expire?

Comment: @Zizouz212 [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/)

Comment: @Yes apt username.

Answer (score 10):

I'll explain it [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct#comment190138_293611):

What "disputed flag" actually means is that *consensus was not reached*.

There is nothing that you need to do about them, except read that [discussion on what to do about the fact that people see disputed flags as something negative that has to be fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293611/103167)

Comment: I am sorry, I think I wasn't clear on what my doubt was. I meant what do with the post that has the flag. As I pointed out i don't mind the disputed flags of the the questions that finally got deleted, because it means they were dealt with I am concerned with the ones that are still out there. And although I could agree not all my flags are correct. In some cases I am pretty sure I was right.

Comment: @Dzyann: Well, your question shows a misunderstanding about what flags are for.  The correct way to deal with "bad/incorrect posts" is to downvote them.  If your flags are being disputed, that's a strong indicator that you should be using votes instead.

Comment: Most of my flags are not being disputed, and more than half of the disputed ones were questions that got deleted. As I realize not all question can be read by everyone I was asking what to do with the flags I believed were right but got disputed, which @Yes have provided. And before asking I read about disputed flags, and they can be disputed by edits, so disputed flags are not necessarily an indicator that I should be doing something else. Also I don't flag so much, but I believe something like "Can anyone please tell me, how to write code in javascript" should be closed.