# "Requires editing" and "Unsalvagable": timing and author disambiguation

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When reviewing some posts I keep stumbling upon some ambiguities of the terms, so I would love to hear some guidelines. Let me describe them.

The first one is the "author" ambiguity. Some questions can be only made good enough by the author (for instance, when not enough info is provided to reproduce the problem). Should I read

- "Requires editing" as "Requires editing from some experienced guys" and
- "Unsalvagable" as "Unsalvagable unless the author edits the post (or at all)"

(1) or

- "Requires editing" as "Requires editing from anyone (may be the author)" and
- "Unsalvagable" as "Unsalvagable anyway: to make this a good question, the author has to ask actually *another* question"

(2) 
There are many questions which I'll categorize differently, depending on the meaning of the terms. Here's an example which is helpful to illustrate the other ambiguity as well: [Error's (PK's and FK's tried in the correct order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261644/errors-pks-and-fks-tried-in-the-correct-order). In the initial post (it can be edited later) there's only error messages. No code, no nothing. It is unsalvagable unless the auther adds their code and expected behaviour. I marked it unsalvagable as off-topic→*"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."* On the other hand, if author edits it properly, it becomes a normal question. So should I go "Unsalvagable" or "Requires editing"?

Now this brings me to another issue, a timing issue. I marked this "Unsalvagable" but if the user edits it and make a proper question, the flag becomes invalid. On the other hand, if I leave it without a flag and the question is not edited, we got a bad question without a flag (although marked as "Requires editing"). Another note is I guess it's ok flagging, despite:

1. when it gets put on hold, there can be no "educated guess" answers ("this error usually appears when .., try .."). Can be (and must be?) added as comments
2. it can be closed before the author makes it good enough. It is probably supposed that they have to take care of their questions quickly enough; though, I had one question which was put on hold as "too broad" and wasn't unsuspended despite my attempts to clarify that it was quite specific, not broad (the point is: "they have to take care of their questions quickly enough" is not always valid)

What timing issue highlight is (2) looks more correct.. in which case my decision to mark that question as "Unsalvagable" is not correct.. this all sounds like it's "how much forgiving we should be?"

Comment: [This issue has been raised before.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues) No one with the power to fix it seems to care.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks, haven't found it because searched for both "requires editing" and "unsalvagable". And what would you say to the second part, the timing issue?

Comment: The timing issue is irrelevant. After you flagged it, it needs at least 5 users with close vote privileges to put the question on hold. They have an option to vote *leave open* if the original reason to cast a close vote no longer fits and the question is good enough to be answered. Review the post as is, don't review based on events that might happen in the future. When needed things can be reversed with re-open votes.

Comment: @rene so, it is actually ok to rise flags which get declined? I thought it's better to try to rise only "helpful" ones.

Comment: You can't know upfront if they get declined. And I have doubts if your flags get declined, I suspect that they are [disputed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295171/what-to-do-about-my-disputed-flags) which has a different meaning. Anyway, once you have too many declined flags you'll get a warning when you raise a flag. You can't have too many disputed flags. Given that you have 500 or so helpful flags I don't think there is much of a problem. So don't worry about it