# Do disputed flags stay disputed for ever?

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags

I have quite a few disputed flags and I would like to know what will happen with them. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295223/4284627), disputed flags mean that consensus was not reached. But will it ever be reached? Will my disputed flags eventually become helpful or declined or will they stay disputed for ever?

Comment: @Servy This explains what they are, but not if they will stay disputed.

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's what happens when you ask like 5 completely different questions in your question, instead of just asking one question.

Comment: @Servy OK, I edited my question so that it is more clear and so that it takes into account the answers to the other question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, 'disputed' is a final status, just like 'helpful', 'declined' and (recently added) 'self-removed'. For all purposes (e.g. flagging bans), you can pretend they weren't cast at all.

Comment: To my knowledge, short of developer intervention, the only flag state that can change after the fact are accepted spam / offensive flags. Moderators can manually convert those to disputed flags to roll back penalties and remove spam / offensive status for a post. That's the only flag category we can impact after a flag has been processed.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, disputed flags usually aren't usually "disputed". "Disputed" is mostly a middle ground between helpful and declined. It's used for things like:

- This isn't spam, but I can definitely see why it was flagged.
- The post flagged comes out of Triage as Looks OK.

So they'll probably stay disputed forever.