# Very Low Quality flag declined on an answer that was both very low quality and technically inaccurate

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441943/4284627) as very low quality and it got declined with this explanation:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I understand that I should not flag wrong answers because they're wrong, but I flagged this answer because it *was* very low quality (bad formatting, spelling mistakes, informal, not enough details), *not* because it was technically wrong (when I flagged it, I didn't even notice that it was technically wrong).

Although my flag was declined, I still think that this answer is very low quality and shouldn't stay there just like that. I could flag it again with a custom flag explaining the situation, but I'm not sure that's the right thing to do.

Why was my flag declined? Is there something I can or should do about it?

**Edit:**

The answer was edited so it isn't as low quality any more. The original answer was:

> i think u better to use float:left it will take care about resiz

Comment: The self "answer" on that page "I decided to change the style because I couldn't order them like that, and now everything is fine. Thanks everyone!" looks more problematic IMO.

Comment: _"The answer was edited so it isn't as low quality any more."_ If the post can be edited to not be "flag worthy" to you, then it's _not_ VLQ. From the flag description: _"This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing..."_ If the post can be edited to be properly formatted and have proper grammar, then _don't flag VLQ._

Comment: @MartinSmith That's true, if you're talking about [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41446257/4284627), I flagged it as not an answer. It wasn't there when I flagged the other answer.

Comment: @Kendra I had a hard time understanding it since the grammar and the formatting were so bad, otherwise I would have edited it. Apparently someone else managed to understand it and edited it to be understandable. I was just surprised that an answer like that isn't "very low quality".

Comment: @Kendra you can also edit "asdfasdfasdf" into "it's better to use float in this situation [and so forth]." I really don't blame the OP here.

Comment: Well, now someone has given it a glam treatment and cleaned up the formatting problems, but it is still low quality. No longer suitable for a flag, but still in need of deletion. We don't have enough tools to take out the garbage, sadly.

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be better to flag it as NAA, it looks rather like a comment to me made by a user lacking the reputation points to post comments

Comment: @Icepickle You won't get any further with NAA than with VLQ, and you'll get even worse contorted legalistic justification when you wonder why. Although in this case there's at least an actionable suggestion in the edited version.

Comment: IMHO Servy's answer is off the mark; you really *did* use the right judgment here. It's more that we suffer from a moderation glitch where the moderator *may* agree with the message of your flag but abstain from acting; choosing to let community review respond instead. I've edited my answer to include this perspective and sequence of events.

Comment: I personally think that anything of quality that low (duplicates included) should be able to be unilaterally deleted by any high-reputation user, and the same should be true of questions too. I'm sick of my google results being full to the brim of questions that have been closed as duplicates, when they should clearly being merged and HTTP 301 redirected to the original.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> bad formatting, spelling mistakes, informal, not enough details

None of those things make a post unsalvageable.  In fact, the first three are even things that *you can fix yourself*.

Those are all things that contribute to an answer being low quality.  When a post is of low quality you downvote it.  VLQ flags are for posts that have no value at all, and no possibility of being salvaged.  They're for things that don't even resemble answers, not for answers that you just think aren't good enough.

The flag most certainly should have been declined.  There is no reason for that answer to be deleted.

Comment: I've flagged similar answers that weren't wrong as very low quality and they were marked helpful, for example [this one on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/1115324/why-do-google-chrome-downloads-stay-at-100-for-a-long-time/1115338#1115338) (there might be better examples on Stack Overflow, but I can't tell which ones since they were all deleted; I specifically remember the answer on Super User since it was an answer to my own question).

Comment: @DonaldDuck I can't see that post as I don't have 10k rep on SU.  Without knowing what the answer said, I couldn't comment on whether or not it merited deletion, or if a mod simply made a mistake.

Comment: The answer basically said something like "it's stuck dude" and then something else that I don't remember. I can't check since I don't either have 10k rep on Super User. If anyone else who reads this comment has 10k rep on Super User, please leave a comment saying exactly what the answer said.

Comment: @DonaldDuck That sure doesn't sound like an answer to the question, correct or incorrect, unless that "something else" happened to be a summary of what might actually be going wrong or how to go about fixing it.  The SO answer you flagged, on the other hand, is providing an answer to the question (even if you don't think it's correct, complete, or well written).

Comment: I can see why it wasn't helpful, but not why it wasn't disputed. According to [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339105/4284627), disputed flags can be disputed because "_This isn't spam, but I can definitely see why it was flagged_". In this case, it was low quality so it's understandable that it was flagged as very low quality but it shouldn't be deleted, which in my opinion fits in on this description of disputed flags.

Comment: @DonaldDuck You're not supposed to flag a low quality post as VLQ.  You're supposed to flag *very* low quality posts as VLQ.  You used the wrong flag, so the flag was declined.  It would have been wrong to do anything else.  Had they not declined it, you wouldn't have realized you did something wrong by flagging posts like that, and would continue to do so, rather than realizing you're doing something wrong by flagging posts just because they're of low quality.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - Moderators can't dispute "very low quality" flags, only accept or decline. [Shog9 has laid out guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288450/19679) for how we should handle these, and I've generally followed those: "Is this an exceptional case where the community isn't able to get rid of trash fast enough? Delete. Else, Decline."

Comment: The effort of editing is only worth expending if there's some value underlying the surface. Even after polishing, this turd has not been magically transformed into a gold nugget. The pooper scooper was definitely the right tool to reach for.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You can certainly argue that the post isn't worth the community spending time editing, that's perfectly fine, I wasn't saying that this post is *worth* editing, rather that it *could* be edited, which indicates that it *is salvageable*, and as such shouldn't be deleted.  When you see a post that you think is a bad answer the solution is to downvote it, not try to delete it just because you don't think it's particularly good.

Comment: @BradLarson ... to which, of course, [my response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339782/1709587) is that the community's only way to (collaboratively) "get rid of trash" *is to use VLQ flags*, so sending negative feedback to users for using them on the basis that posts ought to have been handled by the community is nonsensical. But then, I think that you [already agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314734/1709587).

Comment: @BradLarson so the user was right the post had very low quality, the moderator (you?) may or may not have agreed, the community later agreed, *but* the moderator felt that unilateral deletion was wrong and it should be up to community, which it later was and the community deleted it, and as a result the user had a flag declined, even though the community agreed with the user later. If I actually said that right, then *wow*, it must suck to be a new user here.

Comment: @djechlin The user was *not* right that the post was VLQ.  The user was right that it was of low quality.  They have a downvote to reflect that; that is the appropriate tool for that situation.  The moderator declined the flag because the post doesn't merit a VLQ flag, nor does it merit deletion under the grounds of VLQ, and it would be inappropriate of the user to continue using VLQ in this way, which is exactly what the decline is telling them.

Comment: @Servy you seriously want to argue about how the post was *low* quality but it was not *very* low quality? what are you doing?

Comment: I'm bemused why the moderator broke with the community. The best explanation I have heard is "did not warrant unilateral action when the community could manage the problem." This sounds, well, like how it is, but like it creates a draconian experience for a new user who needs to understand the difference between flagging a post for unilateral moderator action and flagging a post for community review. Especially when new users *flag to close* posts that the community can handle closing.

Comment: @djechlin - Mark already linked to [my take on this flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314679/how-do-vlq-flags-work-whats-their-relationship-to-the-lqp-queue-whats-their/314734#314734). We've always handled these flags as urgent "this needs to be deleted immediately" requests, and been instructed to decline if immediate deletion wasn't warranted, but that's at odds with how many people actually use these flags. You and I agree that there's a disconnect here, which is why I suggested they no longer be shown to moderators.

Comment: @djechlin If you want to argue that the flag is poorly name, by all means, do so, but the flag itself has a well defined meaning, and the answer doesn't meet that criteria, so it was improper to flag it.  Arguing that the name should change because it's confusing is fine, arguing that people should be encouraged to continue flagging posts inappropriately just because the flag name isn't descriptive is not the correct solution to that problem.

Comment: Idk, the more I look at it the more ridiculous I think this whole answer is. "Severe content problems" is covered in the flag description. I've since learned the answer advised the dead wrong thing to do. I guess you could edit it to say the exact opposite of what it already says, but that seems a bit vacuous and not exactly the point of editing (and there are plenty of meta posts yelling at people who do things like that). The formatting problems *were* pretty severe although not quite unsalvageable *if you wanted to format up a wrong answer* so people could more clearly receive wrong advice.

Comment: I've since learned at least one moderator is in favor of changing the system so they don't have to rule on flags like this when community can, and that community deleted the flag, and that people are largely okay with most of how this works. I think I'm just explaining to *you* how the OP did a reasonable thing and picked up some other bugginess in the flagging experience, but the post being of better quality was not one of them.

Comment: @djechlin How do you get from "severe content problems" to "some poor spelling/grammar that doesn't actually inhibit the ability of anyone to actually understand what's being said"?  Again, if you think an answer is wrong, downvote it.  That's the tool that exists to indicate the correctness of answers, not going around deleting answers because you think they're wrong.  That's not what that system is in place for.  It's not like there's nothing for you to do when you see an answer you think is wrong, you simply need to use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @djechlin No, the OP did not do a reasonable thing.  Posts don't get deleted because you don't like them.  That's not how the site works.  The OP made an understandable mistake, insofar as the guidance/UI on how to properly flag could certainly be clearer, but that doesn't mean that the flag itself is any less incorrect.

Comment: "severe content problems" is literally in the description of the VLQ flag. The spelling/grammar problems are comparatively less relevant than this, although I certainly would not fix the grammar in a post telling users to do the exact wrong thing.

Comment: @djechlin Nobody's saying you do have to edit the post.  If you think the post is providing an incorrect answer, by all means, downvote and move on without spending any more time trying to help the author fix it, there's nothing wrong with that.  What *is* wrong is trying to delete a post just because you think it's an incorrect answer.  We don't delete posts because they're incorrect, or short, or lazy, or not well written; those are reasons to downvote, not delete.

Comment: Okay, so you don't like acknowledging the "severe content problem" part of the flag description because it would mean changing your opinion, and you're willfully lying to me about what sorts of posts we delete, for instance the post we're actually talking about right this second. I don't think I can take you seriously on this topic anymore.

Comment: @djechlin I said literally none of those things.  I simply told you that "severe content problems" doesn't mean that a post has some spelling errors, or that you think it's not technically accurate.  That's not what that's describing.  It's not my opinion that you shouldn't flag answers for being wrong, it's *the site's rules*.  That you don't care and plan to do what you want *despite* those rules (and are encouraging others to do the same) doesn't change that, or mean that I'm lying, it just means that something being "against the rules" doesn't stop people from doing it anyway.

Comment: Correctness would fall under content.

Comment: @djechlin You need to keep reading through to the end of the flag description.  **Severe** content problems *that are so problematic that the post needs to be removed*.  It not working is not a content problem that merits it being deleted.  It's a reason to downvote the post.

Comment: ...which it was.

Comment: @djechlin But it wasn't.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41441943/1339987

Comment: @djechlin The fact that a few people ignored the rules for what merits deletion and voted to delete it anyway does not mean that posts merit deletion just because they're wrong.

Comment: You have an opinion on what the rules for deletion are, and other people rightfully ignored your opinion. Like I said I can't really take you seriously here.

Comment: @djechlin It's not my opinion though.  That you want to continue to advise people to keep flagging posts that don't merit the flag, only to end up constantly having their flags get declined, rather than helping them understand the proper usage of the flag isn't productive.  Even if you don't like the current rules, and wish that you could just delete any post because you think it wrong, the fact remains that if you keep flagging posts for that reason you'll just get yourself flag banned.  If you want to change the rule, that's not how you go about doing it.

Comment: Yeah, it's your opinion, you sort of need to realize that on your own. Have you ever read a Supreme Court dissent? After many hours of persuasion by lawyers and deliberation by judges, justices come to different conclusions from the same laws and evidence. I think you're very blind to commonsense and commonly adopted interpretations of about 3-4 sentences of rule text, which I'm sort of okay with but I really don't like the authority with which you are attempting to go out on your own limb here -- on the basis of a quite obviously underspecified rule.

Comment: @djechlin There can be subjectivity involved in the enforcement of rules, yes.  That doesn't mean that everything about every rule ever is entirely a matter of opinion.  It's not a matter of opinion that answers aren't to be deleted just because they're wrong.  If you go out and steal some lady's purse you can't just tell the cops/judge that it's just their opinion that stealing purses is against the rules, and that you don't care about their opinion.

Comment: The "proper usage of the flag" here -- in the views of the moderator involved, myself and several other people in this discussion who are not you -- is that the VLQ description is accurate *but* the moderator will not accept the flag unless urgent unilateral action is needed. Everyone agrees that is a problem that creates bad UX. You are absolutely in the wrong to argue the problem is the post was not actually VLQ. The problem is the mod does not want to act on the VLQ post if the situation is not urgent, which it is not, BUT the community may move to delete the VLQ post, which it did.

Comment: @djechlin By all means, provide the quote of Brad saying that he thinks that this post is VLQ, and that he thinks it merits deletion accordingly, or where he said that you should flag posts because they're factually inaccurate.  Heck, even the OP of the question specifically said that he knows that you don't flag posts for deletion just because they're wrong.  He flagged it because there were some spelling and grammar errors and that it was short; that was why he felt it merited deletion. You are the *only* person here who thinks that you're supposed to flag posts as VLQ because they're wrong.

Comment: Sorry but why do you want me to produce those citations (Brad and related meta discussion on quality criteria for VLQ)?

Comment: @djechlin Because I know they don't exist.

Comment: Meta discussion on VLQ, no, you give me a modicum of evidence you are willing to educate yourself or broaden your opinion and I'll bother to do the legwork of assembling the content I've looked at today in a curated form. You're still being in the wrong for arguing the post was of LQ but not of VLQ and I'm sick of doing that with you. That's your thing now. Which is a ridiculous cross to die on, and you probably understand this in your day job better than you do online.

Comment: The fact that the community elected to delete the post, go educate yourself. Put up a meta question asking why they thought that was a good idea like the OP here took the trouble to do, because clearly you don't have the same opinion on it and maybe stand something to learn from >=3 fellow high rep users.

Comment: @djechlin So because I'm not willing to change my opinion when you state something and refuse to provide any evidence to support it, you're going to continue to refuse to provide evidence to support your assertion?  That's...an odd way to go about things.

Comment: Because you start deliberately rigging my responses to take on the order of 20 minutes and I do not give you the benefit of the doubt that you are acting in good faith, I don't round up evidence for you. If you want to learn something, try it. meta.stackoverflow.com > "Why was this answer deleted for VLQ even after formatting was brought up to par?" that would be a good start.

Comment: @djechlin You expect me to go around searching for Brad saying things that I know full well he never said?  Why would I waste my time doing that.  I know that he didn't say what you've asserted he said, and in response to being challenged to cite your assertion of Brad's opinion, you've instead chosen to say that you don't have to support your statement that Brad said a whole bunch of things and if I want to know if he said them I should look for them myself.  That's absurd.  Clearly you're incapable of support your assertion as to what others have said.

Comment: No, I don't know why you made up that entire response.

Comment: @djechlin Okay, so then provide the quote that supports your assertion.

Comment: Which quote that supports which assertion? We're kind of out on your own limb here.

Comment: @djechlin You've asserted that Brad thinks that this post is VLQ and wants to delete it.  I challenged you to provide the quote that indicates as much, you have openly refused to do so.

Comment: He hasn't done that - what he has done is abstain from using his moderator powers, which necessarily requires declining the flag, because he thought it should go to community review, which it did. What does this resolve?

Comment: He's also taken the opinion that it's unfortunate flag "declines" happen in the process when really the intent is for it to fall through to community review. See his answer here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i which he mostly borrowed from some other answer he wrote which is posted up above.

Comment: You can peruse Shog's answer on the linked question now. It's quite long and you should actually read it, but if I may include the quote, "Well, yeah, there is a problem, and it's the same problem we've always had: "low quality" means different things to different people." You personally seem to see this as less of a problem because people who aren't you are wrong. See the end of his answer as well.

Comment: @djechlin I've said *many* times that there most certainly are problems in conveying to users what the appropriate use of the VLQ flag are, and that what people think it should mean based solely on the name does not accurately describe when it is supposed to actually be used.  I've said that like 5 different times.  That doesn't mean that you should just ignore what those rules are and flag based solely on what you suspect you should do based entirely on the name of the flag, or that there are not rules at all for how the flag is supposed to be used.

Comment: But I've said like 7 times that "when it is supposed to actually be used" is something you're making up and lone wolfing. Then, being surprised when other people have different ideas for how it is supposed to be used, or do not observe the rules as you imagine them. Actually it *does* mean that when you refer to the rules for using the flag you are implicitly assuming the instructions are more specific, agreed upon, and consistent than they are. Your best resolution to this inconsistency seems to be just calling other people wrong.

Comment: I mean feel free to link me to "the rules." You've mostly been referring to 3 lines of *very* obviously underspecified text that has yielded diverse interpretations scattered throughout meta and then sub in *your* interpretation for "the rules." That's b.s., bluntly.

Comment: @djechlin But it's *not* something that I'm just making up.  *You're* just making up your own definition and asserting that it should be what you want it to be in the face of the established rules for it.  Just saying that you're right and I'm wrong, and nothing else, and then insulting me for not changing the entire established position of the community just because you told me to is a nonsensical position to hold.

Comment: I'm asserting there are obviously multiple interpretations and maybe you should learn to live with that. And go a little nicer on inexperienced users who get confused by the existence of multiple interpretations. *That* is what I am asserting.

Comment: Your position is not the established position of the community. You are dreaming. In your own little world as far as that is concerned.

Comment: @djechlin So you're saying that you and you alone represent the views of the established community, and that because you think that you should flag posts as VLQ just for being wrong that that's what the established community position is?  That's not how that works.

Comment: Everytime you type "So you're saying that," just stop with the sentence and start over with something constructive. I said something else, go read it. I explained how your weird worldview arrives in this comment http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340802/very-low-quality-flag-declined-on-an-answer-that-was-both-very-low-quality-and-t/340803?noredirect=1#comment428734_340803 which you have not felt need to address.

Comment: @djechlin Okay, see the help center:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, or this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete, it's duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029  What's your basis for asserting that the community consensus is that an answer should be deleted just because it's wrong or too short?

Comment: First link supports your claim not at all, even contradicts it, but *wow* am I not interested in a word-by-word dissection of it with you. Second link, 4.5 years old. Third link, thanks, OP used their judgment like it's implying you ought to do, so did other community members, it got deleted.

Comment: It seems you're a bit of a strict constructionist though when it comes to posts labeled "guidelines" and "common cases," which is not odd so much as it is wrong, and makes you an odd one out, and gives you some opportunities to be a jerk to new users. So stop doing that.

Comment: @djechlin How does it not support the claim?  It says that an answer should be deleted when it's not an answer.  It says nothing about deleting actual answers just because you think they're wrong or too short, the other posts have been edited over time, not that the behavior in question here has actually changed since those were posted, so unless you have a newer post to actually support your position, besides just you saying so...

Comment: "What's your basis for asserting that the community consensus is that an answer should be deleted just because it's wrong or too short?" knock it off with the strawmen. You're an adult who frequently participates in an online discussion board. So just stop.

Comment: @djechlin So you're saying that you're right because you say so, I'm wrong because you say so, the established positions, rules, and guidelines are all irrelevant, and you should do whatever you want because you're awesome, but anyone else who disagrees with you is wrong and is a bad person for not changing their views to what you tell them to, and other people need to support their position, and when they do, you're allowed to ignore it, and you don't need to support your position because you're just right, and we ought to know better?

Comment: We already talked about what you should do when you want to say "So you're saying that." Mind making a more honest attempt to understand my viewpoint? You can stop interpreting things I say as badly as you interpret the VLQ guidelines.

Comment: @djechlin What makes you think I don't understand your viewpoint?  Your viewpoint is simply factually wrong.  Provably so, by lots of different sources, and you've provided no basis whatsoever to support your viewpoint, you've simply stated that you're right and insulted anyone who disagreed with you.  If you're just going to say that you're going to do what you want, ignore all of the rules, and insult people for telling you that that's not an okay thing to do, then you can't just say that people don't understand you.

Comment: " If you're just going to say that " do you seriously not realize you don't go 400 characters without inserting a strawman?

Comment: " What makes you think I don't understand your viewpoint? " because of the odes you write following the phrase "so you're just saying that," which are not things that I'm just saying. It's...  as simple as that.

Comment: @djechlin It's not actually a strawman.  It's what you said.  You can't just say things and then call people a strawman for saying that you said those things.

Comment: Literally the act of injecting random things as "things I said" is what a strawman is. If you can't discuss without resorting to fallacies constantly (and I mean constantly) then walk away but appreciably don't be a jerk to new users who have a legitimate opinion on a matter of how to participate on SO.

Comment: @djechlin But you are saying those things.  And  you're never explaining why my summaries of your arguments are wrong, you're just saying that I'm a bad person and you're right.  If you would actually explain why your argument is different, then that would actually be an indication that they weren't actually accurate summaries of your arguments.

Comment: Read Shog9's answer from yesterday, thanks.

Comment: Your rate of replacing things I say with "so you're just saying that" followed by things I'm not saying, exceeds my rate of being able to correct misunderstandings. Sorry dude. That's just confrontational behavior and I can't help you with it.

Comment: @djechlin Apparently you don't know what a strawman is then.  Saying that someone said something isn't a strawman argument, saying that someone said something *that they didn't actually say* is a strawman.

Comment: I...  don't need to argue about what I did and did not say. I can't correct you willfully writing other nonsense in. That's just a thing you're doing. If you want to go take a smoke break I can't stop you from doing that either. That would just be another thing you're doing that I have no say in.

Comment: @djechlin So you're accusing me of saying that you said things that you didn't say, but you're going to argue about what you did or didn't say, even though you were specifically arguing about what you did or didn't say? In other words, you're once again just going to say that you're right and I'm wrong and refuse to ever support your position in any way, shape or form.  You do realize that making baseless accusations and then refusing to ever back them up in the face of overwhelming evidence that you're wrong because you're "above that" or something isn't making a particularly compelling case.

Comment: Nice smoke break? K. For better or worse I've learned to be very skeptical of your answers in the future. What people besides you can see is that your method is to take the user's question, assume the *least* charitable interpretation of SO rules and culture possible, and explain why what they did is wrong. No further revision of opinion is possible after that, even after new information enters the light. I feel like an idiot for assembling a long post on how the VLQ standards are out of whack instead of seeing your answer as a one-off fluke. They're not at all.

Comment: "So you're accusing me of saying" do you have a keyboard shortcut for that? Not reading anymore. Sorry. I'm sure you're imagining I'm saying some random thing that helps you get through your day. Why try to argue.

Comment: Glad I caught this and tried to help assure the user something more interesting happened with their flag decline and that the community is not happy with the flag/queue relationship. I explicitly pointed out that your answer is a bit off. You DVed and groused about mine long ago, life goes on.

Comment: @djechlin You literally wrote exactly that like 3 minutes ago.  Is  your  memory that short?  You can go back and read the comment that you wrote just a few minutes ago if your memory is really *that* bad (although if it is, you should probably go see a doctor, because that seems worrying).  Apparently you really just have no idea what you've ever said, and so accuse people of misquoting you because you're simply incapable of remembering what you've already said.

Comment: Given that we have no consistent version of reality between us whatsoever now, bye.

Comment: (Yes, you'll blame me, I already know. Thanks.)

Comment: Servy, to clarify, do you have an example (though note I have <10K rep on all sites) of what *you'd* consider VLQ, or perhaps a more concrete definition? "i think u better to use float:left it will take care about resiz" looks to me, well...very low quality. It's practically gibberish.

Comment: @KyleStrand How is it gibberish?  It's suggesting that they use `float:left`.  They're proposing an answer to the question.  VQL is for things that don't' even resemble an attempted answer; it's for a cat walking across the keyboard, or someone copy-pasting a chapter of a shakespeare play into the answer box.  If an answer is wrong, hard to understand, poorly explained, etc. those are all reasons to downvote, they're not reasons to unilaterally delete an answer.

Comment: @Servy Okay, fair enough. It sounds like for you the distinction is "if any answer whatsoever can be sussed out, it's not VLQ."

Comment: @KyleStrand Indeed, that's the criteria in the help center on the matter: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 18):

Originally I wanted to assure the OP that this was no biggie since there just seemed to be some disagreement between experienced users. But by now I understand the sequence of events more clearly:

- **The answer really was "very low quality."** The moderation response led to confusion, but with the exception of Servy's answer here, there really does seem to be consensus the OP correctly evaluated the answer for its quality, and identified the quality not only as low, but very.
- But the moderator did not want to unilaterally act on it. The policy is that these flags fall through to community review, if there is no urgent action.
- Therefore the moderator *declined* the OP's flag, which is the unfortunate best option here.
- A day or so later, community review (or, possibly attention from this thread -- that happens and sometimes leads to herding) up and deleted the post.
- ...confusing the OP, whose flag to delete the post as VLQ was declined, even though the community declined it as VLQ a day later.

Intermediately, some attention went into fixing the illegibility of the answer, which left it in the state of being a short answer that is also dangerously wrong (I am not a domain expert but this seems the consensus of the meta-OP and comments on the deleted answer). This made its VLQ status more debatable but the review queue deleted it.

**The fix needs to be to not slap the flagger with a "decline" for submitting a reasonable flag.** Moderator Brad Larson has raised this issue before; it is now covered [in this meta request, prompted by this question, to resolve issues with VLQ flagging ambiguity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340866/1339987).

For the record there is some debate whether VLQ should convert into deletes. Servy's answer above strongly argues that if an answer can be edited into a clear state, VLQ is not an appropriate flag, and the answer should not be deleted. There is meta chatter ([for example this comment -- but also answers elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i#comment428216_340866)) arguing VLQ should be used to clear out things that are, well, very low quality, including answers that are some combination of terse, vague, brittle, and wrong. This seems to be how the community prefers to use the flag currently.

Comment: It's entirely reasonable to think that it's of low quality.  I don't see it as a reasonable argument to assert that the answer is entirely unsalvageable and merits immediate and unilateral deletion because it could never possibly have *any* value.  An answer being lazy is a *very* far cry from that.

Comment: @Servy is it reasonable to think that it's *very* low quality?

Comment: No, not given the definition of VLQ.  It unambiguously doesn't meet that definition.

Comment: @Servy anyway the answer is now deleted, so apparently reasonable people differed.

Comment: But it doesn't meet the definition of VLQ, and wasn't deleted as a result of meeting the criteria of VLQ.  In the same way that if you flag an off topic post a spam, it's unambiguously not spam and won't be deleted as such, even if it ends up being deleted eventually because of being off topic.

Comment: @Servy that is 100% off topic from my answer. 1) the mod found it salvageable and turned out to be right. 2) don't be hard on yourself, I would have made the same mistake. 3) in fact, other high rep users did. This is a 1k rep user we're talking about here who **I thought should not take it too hard they got this wrong.** Your answer is correct and it is also hard on him. Good. There should be an upvoted answer to this question explaining the letter of the law. The user should also not take it too hard because *this was not an easy application of the VLQ rule* even if not flagging was correct.

Comment: VLQ doesn't need a rename, it just needs to be removed.  There's literally never any situation where it's the only valid flag.  Any time it would be a valid flag other flags would apply (typically NAA), and so it is only ever a source of confusion.

Comment: The other (serious) problem with the flag decline, besides confusing this flagger, is that the post is no longer up for review. So even if the moderator _did_ want it to be handled by the community, it won't be.