# Why was my abusive flag on a post containing only gibberish declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive

Today, I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995978/4751173) (now deleted) as rude/abusive:

[image]

However, my flag was declined:

[image]

and I'm curious as to the reasons why, because  [common consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/295232) agrees with me:

> #### What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?
>
> ...
>
> This includes posts that contain no useful content at all – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
> > asyuv;laergap897wertp[98 gb;vp98a34

The full reasoning for using this flag in this situation is described in the linked Meta Stack Exchange post, but for me the most important reason is that six rude/abusive flags cast by community members will automatically delete the post. This is more efficient than casting VLQ/NAA flags and having a ♦ moderator delete it; they can spend their valuable time solving problems the community can't solve on its own.

Comment: This is a VLQ target isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean the question to which that 'answer' was posted? I mean, obviously this is a VLQ answer, but I think a heavier flag applies.

Comment: so, to be fair, the post YOU flagged had 2 lines of gibberish. The example has one...... (just trying to be pedantic and find a reason why this makes sense..... I think the help center needs to be edited :/)

Comment: @Patrice, yeah, I know, but I couldn't flag it twice :P

Comment: Well, it's definitely abusive, since it abuses the time of everyone involved...

Comment: That post was flagged with *several* NAA and Abusive flags at once. Perhaps the mod couldn't acknowledge both at the same time, and the system automatically declined the other ones. Not entirely sure about what action the mod took exactly.

Comment: Hmm, "gvd" is a fairly mild expletive in Dutch.  English only here please.  Use the NAA flag.

Comment: @HansPassant This is pretty clearly gibberish. You really can't say that the author there intended for that to be Dutch.

Comment: @HansPassant when we have a help center article that says SPECIFICALLY that these are abusive? ...

Comment: @deceze The timeline shows that the rude/abusive flags were declined explicitly, before the post was deleted. If they weren't, and the post was simply deleted, they would be marked helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant also, as a Christian, I *do* feel a little offended by that expletive (when used in a normal post; I feel fine to discuss about it).

Comment: @Undo Thanks for that clarification.

Comment: Be that an expletive or not, the post is abusive. Being gibberish is enough reason for it to be red-flaggable. We have always flagged those posts as abusive to get them deleted fast, without having a mod involved.

Comment: Hm, well another missing piece of the puzzle. I'll flag them as abusive in the future then.

Comment: Then it looks like an honest mistake by the mod to me.

Comment: "There is no meaning to the post! It's VLQ, it's abuse, it's Not An Answer... There's no metric you can apply that'll narrow that down, because there is no meaningful content to apply metrics to. So pick the flag that speaks to you. I'm partial to "rude or abusive", because enough of them immediately delete and lock the post, which is handy... But VLQ or NAA work just as well in the vast majority of cases..." ([Why don't we treat rubbish the same as spam?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773))

Comment: @gnat if somebody flags it as VLQ or NAA, that's fine with me. I flagged it is abusive precisely because of *enough of them immediately delete and lock the post, which is handy* -> less work for the ♦s.

Comment: I would use the same flag as you, for the same reasons. And I would too complain at meta if my flag was declined :)

Comment: There is a [loooooong argument here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340803/1858225) about just how nonsensical a post must be to warrant the "very low quality" flag. If this is "abusive" rather than "VLQ", then I have can think of literally no content that would be appropriate for the VLQ flag.

Comment: Wouldn't flagging as "spam" be more appropriate than as "abusive" if we're not flagging gibberish as "very low quality"?

Comment: @cpburnz It's not spam though, and we don't want gibberish in the spam detection rules. It is important to use the most appropriate flag and not just assume they all have the same implications. On ELL we're fine with folks flagging for moderator attention when they're unsure, but that might be problematic on higher traffic sites. Abusive/spam flags can block IPs, which may be a little harsh for a VLQ or NAA answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273403/

Comment: @ColleenV It may not technically be spam by SO's definition, but its closer to being spam than it is to being rude or abusive. I admit I'm ignorent in this area, but wouldn't automated gibberish answers follow similar patterns or be precursors to spam? Shouldn't that be fed into whatever the spam system is?

Comment: @cpburnz I don't pretend to know how the system works, but I have been told it's not good to put anything but posts with actual spam messages into the input hopper. I assume we want patterns that can be found in spam messages across the network, and mashing your face into the keyboard is too different each time.

Comment: @KyleStrand: The near-redundancy of VLQ [has been noticed for quite a while](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340866/is-there-any-reason-to-keep-the-very-low-quality-flag-if-not-can-we-remove-i).

Comment: Your flag was abusive. Obviously abusive flags should be declined. /s

Comment: Gibberishish isn't abuse, e.g. use of the p-word outside of the context of beautiful blue Persians. An innocent user can generate that sort of gibberish by having a toddler at they keyboard or thinking he is typing into another app, he shouldn't have "abuses the system" tagged with him.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean true; that's why I personally only use the abusive flag for newly created users (otherwise I usually do use NAA). But this case was a brand new user. Also, if it was really a 'cat on keyboard' case, that user can appeal on Meta, or flag one of his/her own posts explaining the situation, enabling the moderators to reverse the abuse penalty.

Comment: @cpburnz Yes, gibberish can be a spam precursor. But we don't flag it as spam because the penalty on Stack Exchange sites for posting actual spam (intended to make money either directly or via page hits) is very severe. When I see gibberish posts I raise a custom flag clearly explaining that the post consists of pure gibberish & may be a spam precursor; the mods have IP tracking tools, so they can get an idea if the post may be coming from a known spammer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I didn’t know that was the [consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/165773), sorry! Will be sure to approve them in the future.

Turns out it’s possible to change this flag to disputed after the fact, so I’ve done that now.

Comment: No problem, always happy to educate a ♦ :) Could you undecline my flag or is that not possible?

Comment: @Glorfindel: It isn’t, unfortunately. I’ve wanted to do that a few times (and the opposite – delete auto-validation isn’t always helpful), but…

Comment: OK, no problem then, my flag record is good enough to stay out of the ban-zone.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you didn't realize that rude/abusive is used for garbage.  I feel like this is frequently discussed on meta and in chat.  Have you been declining flags like these that have been raised previously?

Comment: *I feel like this is frequently discussed on meta* @JAL - The times I can remember the rude/abusive flag being discussed on Meta it usually devolved into an argument over whether something was offensive enough to warrant the flag. I can't recall a recent discussion on this flag for a post that was pure nonsense.

Comment: @BSMP it comes up frequently in chat, especially one of the rooms JAL frequents. I do not recall any _recent_ discussion of this on m.SO.

Comment: @Ryan I have had one other abusive flag *disputed* (on January 3rd this year), on an answer containing just 100 aaaaaa's. Perhaps one of your colleagues isn't aware of this either, so it might be worthwhile to bring this up in the SO moderator chat.

Comment: @Glorfindel IIRC mods cannot dispute flags, they can only decline them. That would mean that it must have gone into the LQPRQ for some reason (probably was flagged using NaA) and the outcome must have been "Looks OK". That outcome for a series of a's would be a flaggable offense IMO.

Comment: @TinyGiant it was deleted by a moderator three minutes after posting.

Comment: @TinyGiant Spam and Rude/Abusive flags are the only ones mods can straight dispute. This way, they can signal that they understand why it was flagged, but they don't feel that the system penalties should be imposed for whatever reason.

Comment: @Kendra That sounds familiar.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Turns out it’s possible to change them to disputed after the fact, so I’ve done that now.

Comment: Someone needs a second round of hazing :)

Comment: @BoltClock Make him hand draw "afadvadvaserfatea is not useful content" a couple hundred times on some images... ;)

Comment: @JeffC: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZe0T.png

Comment: @BoltClock nice try... handwriting fonts don't count.lol