# Can a declined flag be made helpful flag later by Moderator?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I am curious to know, if a declined flag could be made a helpful one later.

As for the scenario, I flagged a post "very low quality" and it got rejected. What if this same post gets more down votes and more "very low quality" flags, by Guys with High Reputations, after my flag was rejected.

1. Does my flag remain rejected, while other flags get helpful?
2. Does my flag get helpful(after it was rejected), with other flags too?
3. Does my flag get helpful and other flags get rejected?
4. If a scenario like this happens, Does it submit to the same moderator(who rejected my flag) or to another one?
5. Or if first flag is rejected, all flags are rejected and vice versa?
6. Can a Moderator change a flag helpful, after declaring it rejected?

I have searched this question, and I didn't get a satisfactory answer. All these questions may have been answered individually, but I would appreciate answers, related to this scenario.

Comment: Nope, a rejected flag stays rejected.

Comment: Thanks, you just answered first three question. Please also do same with 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: That answers 1, 2, 3, and 6. Old flags don't affect newer flags, answering 5. I covered 4 below in my answer.

Comment: related: [Why was my abusive flag on a post containing only gibberish declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342847/why-was-my-abusive-flag-on-a-post-containing-only-gibberish-declined/342855#comment441998_342855) "Turns out it’s possible to change them to disputed after the fact, so I’ve done that now."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a flag is rejected, it stays rejected. No actions will change the status.<sup>*</sup>

If a post receives more flags later, the post goes back into the queue and any moderator can handle it; there is no per-moderator queue.

A rejected flag also doesn't automatically affect later flags, but a moderator can see if there were previous flags that were handled. So if a VLQ flag was rejected on a post before, and more VLQ flags are cast on it, a moderator might look at the post in more detail the second time to see why it attracted more such votes.

---

<sup>*</sup> Except for *spam* and *rude-or-offensive* flags; because these flags can incur a 100 point penalty to the author and apply anti-spam measures to an account, moderators can mark *all* such flags on a post as 'disputed' (regardless of their current state). Once such flags are marked disputed, they can't then again be changed to helpful or rejected.

Comment: Apart from spam/abusive which can go from helpful/declined -> disputed.

Comment: thanks, but when the post goes back into the queue to the moderator, Can he then make all flags helpful.?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadZulqarnain: no, **no actions** will change the status. Not even by a moderator marking other flags as helpful.