# Fixing a declined flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, flag-ban

My flag was declined after the edits on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038881/trouble-with-xor-of-two-binary-numbers).

I have been through [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116764/flag-declined-after-an-edit-how-can-we-fix-this) so I have clarity why my flag was declined.

I understand that [the declined flag can't be made helpful later](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343466/can-a-declined-flag-be-made-helpful-flag-later-by-moderator).

I also read about the [feature requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107397/indicate-that-a-post-has-been-edited-since-being-flagged). Has this feature been implemented?

What measures are being taken to deal with such situations?

With due respect to moderators that work to review the flagged posts, I'm curious because even after flagging carefully I might run into risk of flag suspension.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: You did flag for closure, right?

Comment: @rene: Yes, for 'unclear what you're asking'. The code was added after the post  was flagged.

Comment: I don't know what to do with people who down-vote well researched, useful and clear posts. They are not kind enough to add the reason why they down-voted. Down-vote is useful if you let know OP the mistake if any so that he/she can improve; without the reason for down-vote it just discourages a novice to be here.

Comment: Voting on meta is different and above all don't cost rep so don't sweat about it that much.

Comment: Are you sure your flag is declined and not disputed?

Comment: FWIW, your flag was not declined by a moderator. It was handled in review; http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15651548, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253827/what-causes-a-recommend-closure-flag-to-be-marked-disputed-versus-helpful-or-de. Also (@honk), moderators cannot lift flag bans.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Obviously I learn more from posting incorrect comments than from reading correct ones ;)

Comment: I smell a bug here. @rene says `disputed` but my account shows `declined`.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Matt said your flag wasn't declined by a moderator -- not that it wasn't actually marked as declined.

Comment: @JonClements then something must have changed in how this works as I was under the impression that declined flags shouldn't happen from review.

Comment: @rene I thought they could if a review reached a consensus that was the "opposite" of a flag... 3x leave open is the opposite of should be closed. I think had it been a mixed big and left open then it'd have been disputed or closed it'd have been marked helpful.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni: there's no bug. Read the second link in my comment "Your flag gets marked as declined if reviewers in the Close Votes review queue determine that the question should be left open while your flag is still pending."

Comment: @Matt: Yes got it after reading the above 4 comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flag was declined, after regular users (no elected diamond moderators were involved) handled the [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/15651548) in the close vote queue.

That task probably got created due to your close flag. As the reviewers now saw a clear question with an MCVE they had no other option then to vote *Leave open* unanimously . As that outcome is the exact opposite of what you flagged, your flag was declined. See also [this answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253836/158100)

Although this is a bit unfortunate there is nothing you could have done differently nor is there anything to fix. Moderators can't retroactively change the flag outcome. Just make sure your next couple of flags are helpful. See [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags)

There are no features or measures planned to get these kind of corner cases fixed. You'll have to live with the occasional declined flag and we with the occasional meta post about it.

Comment: I have edited my question which says my flag was declined.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni right, fixed that in my answer, you're just unlucky

Comment: Thanks the answer nicely explains how the flag was declined! As mentioned in question I know that declined flag can't be made helpful later or flag outcome can't be changed retroactively. But the main question is still on. What features/measures are being implemented to deal with such situations?

Comment: None are planned, nor needed IMHO @ShridharR.Kulkarni

Comment: Loved the very last line of your answer. Thanks for a healthy discussion!

Comment: I'm getting sad until reading your answer. Thank you very much. I'd flagged an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59435024/revisions). He said `You should do this using some JavaScript. I am trying to provide you with a simplified snippet: To be Edited ...` How can't it be spam? Based on @deceze [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392007/do-not-push-posts-into-the-triage-queue-immediately):`The asker had all the time in the world to edit their question into shape before posting it`.The post took 20 mins to complete edited. During that time, I'd flagged it but declined