# How to change Status Flag from Aged away to Helpful

Tags: support, flags

When I am in my flag summary section, I notice that I have 17 flags with Aged Away, when I look to this posts two of them are deleted:

> This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation.

But my flags are still Aged Away. Is it normal? (I think that it will be a helpful flag not aged away).

Comment: Yes, it is normal. The final status of a flag cannot be changed after it has been assigned.

Comment: @honk one exception to that are spam and abusive flags ["which can go from helpful/declined -> disputed"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343466/can-a-declined-flag-be-made-helpful-flag-later-by-moderator#comment445645_343467)

Comment: @gnat: Ah, thanks! As I said some time ago, I learn more from writing incorrect comments than from reading correct ones ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But my flags are still Aged Away. Is it normal? (I think that it will be a helpful flag not aged away).

Flags age away only once. Once they're aged away, they stay aged away. There is no mechanism to retro-actively mark them as helpful. What you saw was probably that you flagged a post, nothing was done about it until your flag aged away, and then someone else flagged the post and a moderator then took action on the post based on that other flag.

It could also be that 3 users delete voted the post, or that it got otherwise deleted (like closed old questions without upvoted answers, these get deleted automatically).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, there is a difference between Aged away and a Helpful flag the thing is if a post was deleted you can suppose that the flag Aged Away will also be deleted

Comment: @YagamiLight Flags always stay. Regardless of whether or not the post is deleted. No flags are ever deleted, even when you retract them they won't be deleted, just set to status "retracted".

Comment: @Yagami those two at the top of your flag summary (I'm guessing those are the ones you're talking about) were close flags that never received any action in the close vote queue so they just aged away. However, those posts were deleted by roomba as they met the criteria (suitably downvoted) but that doesn't count towards a review action for close flags.

Answer (score 2):

Once a flag has "aged away", it's gone forever. The outcome of the question isn't going to affect the outcome of the flag, because the flag simply isn't there anymore. It's as if you never raised the flag in the first place.

And that's why you can't change the status of a flag that has aged away.