# Should this answer be flagged? My "very low quality" flag was declined

Tags: discussion, support, flags, declined-flags

The answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763601/1177200

A screenshot in the event the permalink is no longer working:

[image: answer]

I flagged this question as "very low quality". The flag was declined because:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I agree with this statement. That said, it seems like this answer can be interpreted in two ways:

> run `php artisan config:clear`

I don't find answers like this particularly helpful, but I would not have flagged the answer if this is what the author wrote.

> run `php artisan config:clear` and wo

To me it seems clear that the author started to write an answer and submitted it before finishing it. Maybe I'm missing what the intent is with the ending "and wo", but I shouldn't have to guess. The ambiguity of whether or not the answer was complete was why I flagged it.

I'm OK with being wrong in this situation, but I'd like to hear other opinions. Thanks!

Comment: VLQ should only be used for outright gibberish. This at least includes an attempt at an answer: one should _“run `php artisan config:clear`”_ to resolve whatever issue the question is describing. It’s not a particularly good answer since it doesn’t explain what the command is doing and why this should be the solution. This answer is of little help for future readers. As such, a downvote is appropriate.

Comment: As I observe an attempt to answer is at least an answer even if it was a bad attempt. Mods prefer us to **Downvote** such answer which isn't helpful. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260812/what-qualifies-as-very-low-quality-if-not-this, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340802/very-low-quality-flag-declined-on-an-answer-that-was-both-very-low-quality-and-t

Comment: [The every question and every answer is sacred culture has been taken to the level of absurd!](https://youtu.be/fUspLVStPbk?t=27)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson it's not about every answer or question being sacred. It's about mods and reviewers not expected to be subject matter experts. It fits the attempted answer mold, however horribly, but it does.