# Prevent code from being hidden behind markdown

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695933/4284627) as very low quality. Now the post is completely OK so there isn't any reason to flag it, but as you can see in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41695933/revisions), first the answer was hidden behind markdown and therefore when I flagged it, it looked like this with nothing else:

> This is the answer what you want like abcd efghinj...

This really looked like something very low quality, since it was nothing that looked like an answer (without looking at the markdown). When I flagged it, I didn't think of looking at the markdown and simply thought that the author was just trying to make the site messy or something similar, so I flagged it.

Then the moderator declined it with the reason "declined - The answer was hidden behind the markdown, Kindly edit the post and fix these. It is not a flag worthy post. Regards." and edited it. I have no problem with that, however, there was no way I could guess that the code was hidden behind markdown, so I think that there should be some kind of system preventing this from happening.

It would therefore be useful to implement a system which detects similar cases to prevent this happening. It could detect any HTML code that isn't formatted as code and that [isn't supported in the markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909). This should be implemented in both questions and answers, since answers with invisible code can be flagged as very low quality as in the example above and questions with invisible code can be closed as unclear what you're asking or off-topic because needs a MCVE. When such code is detected, there are two possibilities that I could think of:

1. Post the HTML as plain text, letting the community edit it to format it properly
2. When the OP submits his post, such code could generate a warning like:

   > You currently have non supported HTML code posted as plain text, which could lead to your answer being badly formatted. Please check the preview to see if this is really how you want your post to look. You can press CTRL+K or the {} button to format your code.

   In that case, if the OP decides to submit anyway, a warning like the following could be displayed to anyone trying to downvote or flag the post:

   > Some code in this post may be hidden behind markdown. Do you really want to downvote/flag this post? <kbd>Yes</kbd> <kbd>No</kbd>

I think that a feature similar to one of the above should be implemented to avoid HTML code being hidden behind markdown, like it was the case in the answer that I flagged. The second option would in my opinion be better since it doesn't change what people actually can post, it only generates a warning that will be useful in some cases.

(By the way, I would also like to know why my flag was declined and not disputed. According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339100/do-disputed-flags-stay-disputed-for-ever/339105#339105), disputed flags are used if "This isn't spam, but I can definitely see why it was flagged". Isn't that the case here?)

Comment: "Isn't that the case here?" No, because a VLQ flag is not a spam flag. Spam and rude/abusive belong to a special flag category where it is possible for a moderator to mark as disputed by annulling the flags altogether. When a moderator handles a VLQ flag, it can only be helpful or declined.

Comment: I don't think that this happens often enough to need a ton of special support for it, and additionally if a post really does have serious formatting problems like this a downvote is almost certainly warranted, and a flag is very often going to be warranted (answers that bad tend to not be great answers with formatting problems, they're pretty much always awful answers with formatting problems), so I certainly wouldn't want to discourage people from either voting or flagging such posts.

Comment: Not sure if we need systems to accommodate people who apparently don't look at either the preview or the actual post after they've clicked "submit". It's really not that hard to post something that doesn't look completely terrible, and why people post stuff so absolutely horribly formatted is one of the great mysteries of life.

Comment: @BoltClock OK, I understand why it was declined. But shouldn't it be possible to dispute a VLQ flag in the same way as disputing a spam flag? Disputing a VLQ flag would in my opinion be useful in this case. I think that it's a little bit unfair that a flag should count against me although it would seem correct without looking at the markdown.

Comment: @Donald Duck: I would have marked your flag helpful in that situation along with editing the post myself tbh. Even I don't always think to look at the markdown source.

Comment: (Actually, I'm not sure if a moderator editing a post with a pending VLQ flag would cause that flag to be resolved as disputed...)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker "_why people post stuff so absolutely horribly formatted is one of the great mysteries of life_" Probably because new users don't know that they can format their code. That's why a warning of the type that I described would be useful, since it would teach new users that this feature is available and should be used. Now that I think of it, it would probably be useful to display a warning when code is badly formatted for all programming languages, not just HTML (although the consequences of badly formatted HTML code are much worse than for example badly formatted C++ code).

Comment: To be honest I would have flagged the same. I understand the comment _"declined - The answer was hidden behind the markdown, Kindly edit the post and fix these. It is not a flag worthy post. Regards."_ however it's still low quality because the person who submitted it couldn't even be bothered to comment on their answer to say they were having trouble. Instead they left it and as such to any viewers it provided nothing (unless they chose to edit it).

Comment: @Servy Maybe such an extreme case doesn't happen often enough for that, but I see code formatted as plain text in the review queues all the time. It's just that usually the code is visible, just not readable, and therefore I understand that I should edit and not flag. As I said in the other comment, such a feature would be useful for all programming languages, not just HTML.

Comment: There's a toolbar. There's a help button. It looks terrible in the preview. It looks terrible in the resulting post. If you "don't know that they can format their code" then some warning isn't going to help either.

Comment: @BoltClock Nope, Marking a VLQ as helpful downvotes the post automatically. (Similar with editing a VLQ). That is the main reason why I declined it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker They will probably pay more attention to a big red warning with capital letters and bold text than to some buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: Also @DonaldDuck, Regarding the FR, I liked the idea. There is already a warning that comes when you post unformatted code. So perhaps it might be easy to extend that to flag dialogs too. But as others have mentioned, I think it's too much dev stuff with too little use cases.

Comment: @Jinx88909, There was a comment left by them on their post, I deleted it after I edited the post.

Comment: @BhargavRao then I retract my comment.

Comment: @BhargavRao You're right, I just noticed that when I tested writing unformatted code. I wonder why so many users don't pay attention to it. It might be useful to make it impossible to post such content for users who have a very low reputation score (for example less than 10).

Comment: I think every one of us has gotten bitten by this at least once.  But then you learn to keep an eye out for it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, I think the text is somewhat ambiguous for new users. That particular user whose post you flagged, Did add 4 spaces in front of their code. However they did not add a small extra line. There's a communication issue there for sure (As an aside, I too have been fallen for bad MD a lot, and got a few helpful flags by non looking mods! It was only when I started monitoring answers using the API and getting the complete post that I managed to understand this. In hindsight, whenever you think that a post is gibberish, open the edit window once, You might find failed spam attempts too)

Comment: @BhargavRao I just tried copying/pasting the exact markdown of the original answer into a new question (that I didn't post of course), and this time I didn't get the warning. The person posting the answer therefore had no idea that the answer would turn out badly formatted if he didn't understand that the preview was a preview. I think that this bug should get fixed so that code that would turn out unformatted always generates the warning.

Comment: @Donald, Interesting, So the SE Broken Code Detector™ is not able to detect that the code is broken when there's 4 spaces in front of the code. That's the real issue then. Or perhaps the detector cannot do better than that. But, thanks for testing that out, TIL.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've asked a new question with the [bug] tag about that issue here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341763/no-warning-when-code-is-badly-formatted-when-its-indented-4-spaces-but-no-line

Answer (score 4):

First off, I wouldn't let one declined flag worry you. If the rest of your flags are OK, then it's not going to affect your ability to raise flags in the future.

Secondly, as [BoltClock points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341750/prevent-code-from-being-hidden-behind-markdown#comment433814_341750) the only flags we can "dispute" are Spam and Rude or abusive flags. All other flags can only be marked as "helpful" or "declined".

Thirdly, in cases like this where the answer looks incomplete it's always worth checking the source to see if there is any xml-based markup code that's not displayed correctly (e.g., html, XAML, Android view markup, etc). In most cases there is and the simple addition of a blank link or an extra couple of spaces will reveal the post in all it's "glory". At that point you'll probably want to do further edits, down-vote, comment or even flag it as it's highly likely that there are other things wrong with the post.

Yes, you might forget to do this from time to time - we all do - but it is worth trying to make this a habit.

Comment: I'm not that worried about the flag, I just used it as an example to show that the feature request would be useful (and it's also this case that gave me the idea). I think that the feature that I'm asking for would more generally let new users know that it's possible to format code and that not doing so can have unexpected results. I see badly formatted code in the review queues all the time, and this feature might help new users to format their posts better.