# No warning when code is badly formatted when it's indented 4 spaces but no line is skipped

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, error-message

When discussing unformatted code on meta, I noticed that there is a bug in the warning that says that code isn't formatted. For example, if I enter this, the warning works fine:

[image: warning]

However, the following didn't generate any warning, and as you can see in the preview, the code is still badly formatted:

[image: no warning]

This issue caused an answer to be badly formatted. You can read about that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341750/prevent-code-from-being-hidden-behind-markdown).

I think that this should get fixed so that the warning appears every time the code would be badly formatted. Otherwise new users have no way of knowing that their code will be badly formatted when they don't skip a line.

Comment: Agree completely that this *is* a bug. The SE Broken Code Detector™ must be made to realize that without adding a new line between the code block and the paragraph, the code is wrongly formatted.

Comment: *"have no way of knowing"*... except for the blank preview, of course. Still a bug, but I don't think we need to hyperbole.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's true. Although they might not understand that it's a preview. In the screenshots I posted it's obvious that it's a preview, but that's not always the case.

Comment: Thank you for reporting it. I'm looking into it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your report. The SE Broken Code Detector™ was running through the raw text block without "remembering" the previous lines, and therefore incapable of detecting flaws like the one reported. This issue has now been fixed and should be up with our next prod build (aka, whatever comes after `rev 2017.1.17.24712`).

Comment: Just curious, `24712` is the total number of builds?

Comment: @Veve yes. However, build counts are based on our dev builds - which is why we saw a jump from 24712 to 24718 in prod today. It also changes depending on configs, and whether or not we reset them (not sure we ever did, but it would be possible)

Comment: @rla4, What algo does SE use to detect unformatted code blocks?

Comment: @BhargavRao nothing that fancy. We run through lines that look like code (some regex + keyword checking) and verify how many of them start with 4 consecutive spaces.