# Disputed flag after 'Unsalvageable' in Triage

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Sometimes I do spend a little time in the Triage queue. This question came up: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8165073 and I marked it as unsalvageable.

When you mark something as unsalvageable, you have to flag the reason, which I did.

The consensus apparently was that the question merely 'should be improved' my flag got disputed.

After that the question was put on hold, because, frankly as it is the question is unsalvageable.

I don't know if this is the intended behaviour by the creators of the site, but it sure doesn't help with my willingness to mark something as unsalvageable. Maybe I just should skip those.... (of course I shouldn't skip them, but it just feels wrong).

Edit: meh... instead of posting this, I could have just searched meta a tiny bit better: [Auto-convert disputed flags when they prove to be correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct) sums it all up.

Comment: I do wonder about the person who marked it "**Looks OK**". But yeh, this is one of the problems with triage. Try not to let it demoralise you, on average slightly more than half your flags should stick, hopefully. :)

Comment: You can skip anything you want. There's nothing wrong with that. If you consider that you can't (or won't) do a good job of reviewing a particular entry, skipping ensures that at least you won't do a *bad* job. It is the responsible thing to do in such cases.

Comment: @NathanTuggy yes, I understand that, but I'm talking about skipping all unsalvageable questions just because a lot of people will just mark them as 'should be improved'. That doesn't help either.