# Why my flag is count as disputed

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

When I was checking the site then I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773593/how-to-display-single-quote-in-ms-word-by-using-tiny-but-strong-php and raised Unclear What you are asking flag. but it was marked as disputed and when I visit that question it was close as Unclear What you are asking, I don't understand why, where  I was wrong?

Comment: You probably weren't wrong. Flags can get disputed from review queues (particularly Triage where people tend to select "Should be Improved" more than they should).

Comment: Disputed just means that *someone* disagreed with it - evidently at least five people didn't, hence the question is now on-hold. See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293611/3001761 for a feature request to alter this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/208490/find-the-reviews-for-a-post) when search by id of the post (30773593), it shows that question was in the Triage queue, where the final result was "Should be Improved".

This "Should be Improved" result will invalidate any current close flags as "disputed".

Don't worry about the disputed flags. The Triage queue is known for getting many questions incorrectly acted upon, by sending them to the Help and Improvement queue instead of voting to close. Disputed flags don't harm you in any way.