# When my unsalvageable review is disputed in triage does the question still go through Close Queue?

Tags: discussion, triage, disputed-flags

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/244049) a common cause for a flag entered from the triage queue being disputed is when I recommend that  the question be closed, but the result of triage isn't unsalvageable, but either OK or needs editing.

In that case, does the question still get added to the close queue?

Would processing be different if instead of hitting unsalvageable in the triage queue, I had opened the question, and flagged from that page, skipping the review on the review page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Shogs [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) he includes a flow chart to show how it works:

[image: flow chart of triage queue processing]

If I'm reading it right it looks like the post does not leave triage until a outcome is obtained.  If either looks okay or should be improved are picked the flag is disputed and it either gets full visibility for the former or hits the help and improvement queue on the latter.  This leads me to believe that your flag would not put it into the CVQ.

It appears from the answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296769/why-my-flag-is-count-as-disputed) and [this comment from a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) that any flag will be marked as disputed, not just flags from the review queue.  If that is indeed true then the only way to get it into the CVQ would be to flag after triage is completed or close vote as triage does not affect close votes.

Comment: Hi.  Could you add an adequate image description to understand the image you linked without looking at the image?  I'm totally blind, and the image doesn't help at all.  (Consider this a friendly reminder about why image descriptions are valuable to some of us).  Also, I want to confirm.  You did not answer the part of the question about whether processing within the queue is different from a flag posted at the same time while the question is still in triage.

Comment: @SamHartman I'm not sure what happens if it is flagged outside of the queue.  I'm trying to see if there is anything on meta about that.  Also, thanks for the information about the image description.  It never even dawned on me that I should put something there.

Comment: @SamHartman It appears from the answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296769/why-my-flag-is-count-as-disputed) and [this comment from a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) that any flag will be marked as disputed, not just flags from the review queue.

Comment: `Unsalvagable -> Flag Review -> Declined -> Full Visibility?` This seems odd to me. Anything that was originally flagged as unsalvagable shouldn't go straight to the home page if that flag is declined. That is, if it was bad enough to get that flag, but not actually worthy of it, wouldn't it still need to be edited? i.e. sent to the help and improvement queue. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Draco18s A lot of the times it does.  It is just that once you are in the CVQ/mod flag queue, you can no longer send a question to the HIQ.  The only way to get there is from requires editing in triage.