# Too many "Looks OK" in Triage on Unsalvageable questions

Tags: discussion, triage

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8215956

This is happening way too much.  Every time I see one of these a little chunk of my motivation to do triage dies.  I go away for a few days and come back with somewhat renewed enthusiasm and quickly get discouraged again by how many users with >1000 rep don't seem to have assimilated the basic rules of what makes a good question.  The most discouraging part is I don't see a way to fix the problem.  Maybe I need a LONG break from SO.

Comment: soo... what exactly do you want to discuss? The problem of the triage-queue has been named all over meta. Sure it's discouraging, but this is probably the lesser of two evils.

Comment: The only one solution for you I guess would be to make a request to up the min score for accessing review queue or make an exam with high passing score before giving the access.

Comment: Increasing the minimum reputation required for access to triage probably wouldn't have a noticeable impact on the results.

Comment: Increasing reputation requirements has already been discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295051/464709).

Comment: Here's a couple more you might enjoy! http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8516030 A chunk of code which "doesn't work. I'm stuck ... Thank you in advance" with no problem statement but it Looks OK! One of the "Looks OK" guys also thought this off-topic question about networking "Needs to be improved" http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8516011 I think its widely known there is a problem, the question is what to do about it? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291371/please-let-us-re-flag-disputed-triage-questions?lq=1 might be a good start.

Comment: Well, as someone new to reviewing on SO, I have to say that it took a lot of searching for me to figure out how the triage process is expected to work. I would imagine a lot of people can't be bothered to go hunting for this information and it is not presented anywhere obvious. I looked at the FAQ questions, nothing in there. No instructions on the triage page. I eventually went searching through Meta till I'd read enough to satisfy myself that I knew how to triage.