# VLQ flag declined, but question later deleted. Confused

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

Yesterday I came upon this question, [Free football XML feed (Leagues, Players, Team etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541170/free-football-xml-feed-leagues-players-team-etc), and flagged it as an off-topic question, asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. Four other users also did the same and the question was closed. The question was then later deleted by a mod. No problems there.

However I had also flagged the sole answer to that question as very low quality. It's entire text is ["www.livexmlsports.com - it's free but as i understand it only has livescores"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29458786/616443). My logic was that this question was in fact low quality (just a link) and it fit well within the VLQ close reasons, yet it was declined with the reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I didn't flag the answer as "not an answer", which is typically when I see that canned response, so I'm not sure why I'd see that as the reason for it being declined.

Did my VLQ flag go through the review queue and then get rejected by other users (incorrectly IMO)? Was I wrong to flag that answer as low quality?

Comment: these were _not_ regular LQ queue reviewers who decided on your flag - because if thay did, flag would be resolved as [disputed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253117/839601), not declined

Comment: The question needs to go away.  The answer is a trivial part of the overall issue.  The flag therefore becomes noise.  I'm not sure how long the mod queue is currently, but I'd wager it's in the hundreds, if not over 1k.  Think of it this way--someone dumped a load of dog sheet on your front porch.  Do you call an exterminator for the flies?  No, you get out your snow shovel and your catapult.  No need to flag bad answers on a bad question.

Comment: @will Spot on with the understanding of the mod queue and the metaphor.

Comment: Unfortunately, for the metaphor to be accurate, you have to aim the catapult at a dumpster, and not the person who dumped the load on your porch.

Answer (score 11):

There's really no need to flag that answer when the question is the real problem. We frequently see people flagging link-only answers as "very low quality" or "not an answer" when they are, in fact, answers to the question that was asked, as is the case in the example you gave. We want to deal with the root problem, which is the off-topic question, so we'd prefer if people just flag/vote to close those instead.

Comment: yeah let's keep the "answer"... and the question too, in case if asker decides to grab extra 2 rep by accepting. Why spoil the [old romance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/839601)

Comment: Hmmm, so if the question wasn't off-topic and in reality viable, should the answer have not been flagged as vlq?

Comment: @gnat The question and answer are both deleted in response to flags on the question, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @gnat It was an old question from 2011 or so that would have been roomba'd in 9 days.

Comment: @j08691 Does the answer meet the criteria for flagging as VLQ in either case?

Comment: This is one of those cases where I think "very low quality" does apply, particularly since their other answer was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29458838/19679 . It looks to me like this was spam.

Comment: I personally wouldn't have accepted it as VLQ; mostly because the answer is just a symptom of a really, really, poor question. I might have seen a spam flag being accepted though.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker So if a VLQ answer is a result of a really terrible question, the question is what warrants the flag, and just leave the answer?

Comment: ["Marking a flag \[declined\] was designed to deter serial abusers of the flagging system, but we find that this “slap on the wrist” is being used more often than is beneficial..."](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/)

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes. Dealing with the question will deal with the answers too. Flagging them both doesn't really do anything but add flags to the queue.

Comment: @gnat Nice try, but that was superceded by this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently

Comment: @gnat That was nearly five years ago. We're dealing with a completely different volume of flags now.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker nice try, if only not [even more recent changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/165773) that suggest LQ reviewers are able to handle these flags without mod involvement

Comment: @BilltheLizard I never considered that, and would have flagged both question and answer quite confidently. Thanks!

Comment: @BilltheLizard as opposed to [what was five years ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251175/839601) currently most of these flags are expected to be handled by tens thousands reviewers in LQ queue

Comment: @gnat And if those flags don't get handled in a timely manner in the review queues, they get escalated to mods. The community has first crack at them. If they don't handle them, we have every right to decline them.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to what Bill said.

I processed the flag from the queue so I was concentrating on the answer rather than the whole picture - this meant that I clearly didn't see just how bad the question was.

Looking at the answer it did appear to be an attempt at an answer - just one that should have been edited/down-voted rather than immediately deleted. A flag on the question would have been more effective.

Comment: Is it possible that you are seeing an early [spam seed](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/84561/30204) here?

Comment: @MichaelT - Probably not, given that the question was asked in 2011 and sat without an answer until yesterday. Spam seeds tend to be asked and answered within hours, if not minutes. I think it was merely a poor question that tended to invite spammy answers.