# Flagged post disputed for Duplicate but marked as duplicate eventually?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged a post three days back since i feel it's a duplicate of other posts which already has an answer.

Here's that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889019/how-can-i-get-parent-class-activity-name-in-android), i've marked as `duplicate` for [this already existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967799/how-to-know-the-calling-activity-in-android) which had an answer.

In my flagging post history it show `Disputed`.

[image]

but, why eventually the same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889019/how-can-i-get-parent-class-activity-name-in-android) marked as `Duplicate` for the same post which i pointed and why did i get declined?

> Well, this is not the first time but what this makes me is not to
>   touch the flagging post part as i get disputed for no good reason even
>   that's useful.

Comment: Note the *disputed status* is different from *declined* status. I'm not 100% sure, but *disputed* appears to be used primarily when there's some kind of procedural complication processing your flag. See [What is a disputed flag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) and [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags) Maybe a mod manually disputed it, though; I don't know.

Comment: and this one http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253117/1380752

Comment: I don't know if the gold badge marking it as a duplicate caused it to be "disputed" but I wouldn't think so. That should mark it as helpful but I'm not completely sure how it works behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you hover over the `disputed` text for that flag and see what date/time your flag was marked disputed?

Comment: @apsillers  April 27   7.07

Comment: The [OP of that question](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3592176/user) was put on suspension some time shortly after asking that question (for something totally unrelated to that question). Maybe that had something to do with it? Again, disputed flags are usually due to some kind of procedural complication that makes the system believe the flag is obsolete. Maybe suspension automatically disputes all flags on a user's posts?

Comment: Nope, nevermind; this user was not suspended until at least 4-28-2015.

Comment: I think I remember reading somewhere that once disputed, a flag will not change status, even if the action is taken. I think the flag gets "marked as treated" (something like that) as soon as any of the three possibilities (helpful, disputed, declined) is decided

Comment: I came to this post because I was going through my disputed flags (which in proportion are a lot) and there are many correct duplicate flags disputed, and also correct close flags disputed (I wrote correct since they have been actually closed), and from the meta-posts above is probably because many people said it was okay or just needed editing. It is a bit frustating

Comment: Came here while searching for an answer to the same issue in my flagging history, and found this meta post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311234/duplicate-flag-disputed-yet-question-closed-as-duplicate . Apparently flags can be auto-disputed if three people click "Looks OK" in Triage, so that might be what happened.