# Duplicate flag disputed, yet question closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, disputed-flags

Yesterday, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926032/given-a-string-return-true-if-the-string-bat-and-ball-appear-the-same-numbe) as a duplicate from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string)

To my surprise, my flag got disputed but the question got closed as a duplicate of the same question I flagged it for. ~looking confused~

I found a lot of meta questions on this, so it seems to happen more often. What I don't understand (and can't find) is why it happens and what I should do about it (if anything)?

Comment: That does seem odd, since the person who finalized the closure [also appears to be the only reviewer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10339316).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Jarrod Roberson has a gold java tag (dupe hammer).

Comment: Yes, @DavidPostill, I meant that, given the result of the review was closure, it's odd that the flag was disputed. Initially I figured that he hadn't come by the question via review at all, but that the review had been completed as "leave open", and then Jarrod found it later and closed.

Comment: I'm fairly confident the flag was disputed because the post was marked as "looks ok" [during triage](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/10338099). Per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/163863, this will dispute close votes. This would then make your question a dupe of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298423/disputed-flags-questions-closed-for-the-same-reason.

Comment: @JoshCaswell OK. Then we need to wait for the mod who handled theflag to comment.

Comment: No mod handled the flag, @DavidPostill: the flag was handled _by Jarrod_ in the close vote review queue. Edit: unless it was handled in Triage, as Matt just said.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I now understand what has happened. Maybe my question is a duplicate of the one you mention, however that question hasn't really been answered, nor is the feature request in it accepted or denied. But I could flag my own meta-question here as a duplicate and see if it gets disputed ;-)

Comment: Maybe it was a mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, I conclude that the answer to **what happened** is that other reviewers didn't think the question was a duplicate (or in my opinion were to lazy to look carefully). After three reviewers voted "Looks OK", my flag was automatically *disputed* (which is something completely different than *declined*).
Then Jarrod Roberson came along, decided it's a duplicate, and because he has a gold java badge, closed the question on his own.

The answer to **"what I should do about it"** is probably: nothing.
It would however be nice if someone responded to the feature-request in the questions below:
[Auto-convert disputed flags when they prove to be correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293611/auto-convert-disputed-flags-when-they-prove-to-be-correct)
[Disputed flags & questions closed for the same reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298423/disputed-flags-questions-closed-for-the-same-reason)