# Disputed flag should be overturned to helpful when marked as such

Tags: feature-request, flags, disputed-flags

Disputed flag should be overturned to helpful when marked as such. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Another user with the same issue can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291926/flagged-post-disputed-for-duplicate-but-marked-as-duplicate-eventually). I think the system should, in these cases, revert the disputed to helpful as eventually someone else came to the same conclusion as the original flag, and the post was marked as such.

Comment: What's with the lack of freehand red circles? It makes it really hard to tell exactly what you're trying to address! :p

Comment: It was my first foray in GIMP. Still trying to get used to ubuntu, lol.

Comment: *"Another user with the same issue can be found here"* So, you're saying this post is a duplicate? ;-P

Comment: That was more of a discussion @MikeMcCaughan. I'd like to see this as a feature request, and see this changed in the future.

Comment: @FrankerZ Don't worry, I wasn't going to mark it as a duplicate. I don't want to get something disputed. Also, *winky smile with tongue sticking out" denotes sarcastic joke in my world :).