# Shouldn't flags such as "close flag due to off-topic" marked as unhelpful be remarked as helpful when a moderator later on closes for same reason?

Tags: feature-request, declined-flags, disputed-flags, flag-history, helpful-flags

Shouldn't flags such as `close flag` due to `off-topic` marked as unhelpful be remarked as helpful when a moderator later on closes, especially if for same reason?

E.g. [A question closed as off-topic in 2015 and deleted, yet my close as off-topic flag from 2011 was declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849641/can-i-use-codeproject-open-licensed-program-in-a-gpl-program) and [another example of the same, flagged 2011, closed 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219339/how-do-i-handle-a-developer-who-was-previously-amazing-but-now-lack-luster).

Since the number of helpful flags are counted towards badges, then flags that were ultimately correct (after incorrect moderation was overturned), should be counted as helpful.

Related Question (for different flag type): [Disputed flag should be overturned to helpful when marked as such](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329487/38368)

Comment: Yes. Yes, it should.

Comment: For one thing, rules change over time: your flag might have been incorrect or unwarranted in 2011, yet closure became appropriate 4 years later in 2015. However, I'm not claiming that was the case in your examples. In your examples, your initial flags were not dismissed by moderators, but rather by the community. At any rate, I'm very uncomfortable with going back and changing history. There is virtually no precedent for this, and I don't see the advantage.

Comment: @CodyGray, The Doctor has been doing this since 1963. Besides, every new idea starts out as something new, if you're uncomfortable with changes, your choice of profession is peculiar, as the essence of what we do is rapidly changing things. One more thing, deleting a highly voted question with many answers is sort of erasing history and moderators do this without mercy.

Comment: I don't know if that was some kind of pop culture reference, or what, but the first part of your comment didn't make any sense to me. As for the last part of your comment, as I said before, no moderators were involved in *any* of the questions you cited, neither in declining the flags or in deleting the questions.

Comment: Must be a [Doctor Who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who) reference.

Comment: @CodyGray my last point was that the moderation act of deletion (in general, not in the specific examples I gave) is a form of "going back and changing history". Therefore, there is precedence for this in SO.

Comment: Deletion doesn't change history. All deleted posts are preserved.

Comment: I know, I can see them, however most users can't.