# Why was this off-topic flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I flagged the Stack Overflow post *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984454/lenth-limit-of-sharelatex-document* as off-topic.

To me, it is just about limitations on the website tool. I looked it up a bit and didn't find a thing about such a limitation. So I suggested to use the contact form available on the website.

Was I wrong flagging this or not?

Question (because it's deleted):

> I've written a document on SHARELATEX Web site. I wonder if a document must have a length less than 100 pages.
>
> Please I need your help!
>
> [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex)

Comment: I don't think so - it's neither a good quality question nor a good fit for the site. Probably just a moderation mistake; it happens.

Comment: ok :) and now the question is closed because off-topic --' Is the flag be changed as helpful or not?

Comment: No, a flag's status won't change once it has been set. But disputed flags don't count against you in any way, so try not to worry yourself too much over it.

Comment: I found [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293509/983430) very helpful in understanding what happens to make flags "disputed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why was this off-topic flag disputed?

Your flag should have sent the question into the Close Vote review queue, but there were no reviews in that queue (I checked). Instead it was in the triage review queue three times:

- marked as [*should be improved* and *unsalvageable*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7905113)
- unanimously marked as [should be improved](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7905256)
- unanimously marked as [unsalvageable](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7905556)

The other close votes probably piled up organically outside of the queues and now it is deleted.

The question is, **should flags be disputed when a verdict is reached outside of the queue**. I think **it should**, because close voting outside and inside of the queue is different. When reviewing in the queue, it is possible to review the question as *Leave Open*. This is not possible outside of it, so there is no chance for a user to say that the question should not be closed.

> Was I wrong flagging this or not?

This is all kinds of unclear and off-topic.

1. I have no idea what the *question* is in that question.
2. This doesn't have anything to do with programming. It might be better suited for [webapps.se](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

So, you did the right thing flagging this.

Comment: That queue only started *after* the user asked this question, perhaps as the result of a flag being raised by another user. Can the same post enter the same queue twice?

Comment: @TZHX Yes, a post can enter a queue twice, but not at the same time. A post can be at the same time in different queues.

Comment: So, possibly the question went through two rounds of Triage -- the first one leading to Soma's flag getting disputed?

Comment: @TZHX Good thinking. It was there three times. I just didn't have the patience to look farther through the many many pages.