# Why was this “off-topic” flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-flags

I flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862901/is-there-an-invisible-browser-other-than-ghostzilla-which-is-stopped-developing) as off-topic, as in my opinion it is asking for an off-site reference or resource but my flag was disputed. To improve my 'flagging' in the future, can someone tell me why it was disputed?

Comment: It was disputed because whoever reviewed the flag has no idea what they're doing. Not only is the question clearly asking for an off-site resource, it also has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: You also might want to look at this question: [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy although I must say I didn't know the exact difference (so thanks) I thought this was an obvious example of a question that should be flagged like I did so any outcome other than helpful is weird in my opinion and l4mpi seems to agree.

Comment: Deleted now....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also flagged this as off-topic during [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8459570).

However, the consensus was (wrongly in my view of course) that it "should be improved". I would assume until a moderator or more informed user can tell us otherwise that it is disputed because we flagged while Triage was underway and the other reviewers disagreed with us. I'm getting an awful lot of disputed flags these days, which I believe is due to Triage and people not clicking "Unsalvageable" when the question meets one or more flag criteria. The disputed status remains even if the question is eventually closed or deleted. I have learnt [not to worry about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253117/397817).

Comment: I agree. The only way this question could have been edited into a SO-worthy question would be if the OP would program his own alternative to the browser he requested and got stuck at a certain issue and posted that as the question...

Comment: You did the right thing Peter, as evidenced by the question now being zapped. Keep on doing the right thing and don't worry about the disputed flag.

Comment: Why are people with under 1000 reputation, and have been here less than a year, reviewing items?  It can take a while to get a feel for the site, and clearly those two don't know how to review.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Wait, you think that using the review queues is about improving the quality of the site, and not just a minigame for people to entertain themselves?  How quaint.

Comment: @Servy - I know, I'm old-fashioned and borderline-delusional like that

Comment: Triage is badly broken.  People are voting LooksOK on lots of garbage questions.

Comment: After reviewing some of the Questions you've marked as 'Closed' I can see why they would be re-opened. We need to do a better job as helping other's and less of a job at shutting them down when they ask questions.