# Should I Comment After Flagging a Post?

Tags: discussion, flags

My understanding is that flags can be disputed depending on certain changes including edits. With that in mind, I generally won't both comment and flag the same post. I will either flag if flagging seems appropriate, or comment if the situation seems more nuanced/needs to be figured out first.

My thought is, if I flag something as unclear, then comment that it's unclear that could lead to an edit that's insufficient to resolve the issue but still disputes my flag. I prefer instead to save my flags and use them when they can speak for themselves.

However, in some cases it could benefit the poster for me to point out exactly what is unclear, or that the reason their answer is MCVE is because it's lacking any error message. In those cases I will generally comment and defer flagging unless the poster has attempted to fix it and failed to address the issue. Should I be doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't let the disputed flag stop you from leaving a comment on the question as having the OP improve the post so that it doesn't need to be closed is better in the long run.

Comment: what's your end goal? 100% relevant flags, or making stack a better site? :)

Comment: @Patrice is is possible to get 100% relevant flags if you have already 10+ disputed ones, because if so then yes

Comment: @Patrice A better site of course (100% is a pipe dream...). But part of my concern is that I'd invalidate other's flags and interrupt the process with a comment that might not be as suited to explaining the issue.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan well honestly, if I flag a question because (I don't have time/I'm lazy/I'm cranky today/I need to get a coffee) I don't wanna comment on it, and you come in, comment, make the OP change his post and make it fit StO, then I wouldn't even be mad about an invalid flag. The process' ultimate stage is to make the post on topic, clear and relevant. I don't really care how it happens. If your comment doesn't make the post clearer/more on topic, then it'll be closed anyway, no?

Comment: @ciaran82 I GUESS if we round up after like the 10th digit, you could eventually get close enough? :P

Comment: looks like I need to get about 99800 in a row 100% correct, challenge accepted

Comment: @ciaran82 what's sad is that, when you think about it.... if you didn't have a limited number of flags, you could probably find that amount of just off-topic new questions in a month...

Comment: @Patrice true, but more of a challenge with a limit :p

Comment: @ciaran82 then good luck to you my friend :P Check back with me in a little while to let me know how you're doing :P

Comment: @Patrice It might be a few years time before I could get near that number I on average do about 20 max a day so in 15 years I will let you know if I succeeded

Comment: It's always good practice to let people know who needs to be revenge-downvoted.

Comment: @Will - Only if you're telling folks with 125+ rep that you're down voting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is.  If your main goal is to be helpful and improve the community, then **flagging while leaving comments is a great idea**.  This can prevent a question from being closed in the first place.  And as a more personal touch, I think that the OP would better learn how to improve the question.  The canned close reasons are not bad, but they aren't always the most accurate to every situation.  Whereas you, as a human, can give a more specific and relevant comment.

If your goal is increasing the number of flags marked "helpful" then flag without leaving the comment.  Worth noting is that ["disputed" flags don't count against you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags?rq=1), which is what will happen if the question is edited before your flag is processed.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to go ahead and flag a question even if you want to leave a comment. You have zero control over whether *someone else* either tells the OP what's wrong with their question or just edits the question themselves. The OP may edit the question when they see the down votes even if no one comments.

There is no way to ensure your flag or other folks' flags won't get disputed. If you use flags correctly, it should be fine.