# Flag disputed on "I'm having this problem too" Answer

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer, disputed-flags

I recently found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32157874/2415822) about integrating the MapBox API into a iOS Swift project.  I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32161772/2415822) as NAA because it does not really attempt to answer the question, and is mostly an "I'm having this problem too" answer.  The flag was disputed.  Am I missing something?  I don't really see an answer in that post, unless it's a really convoluted way of saying "don't update to the latest version of the MapBox SDK."

Comment: Please do read [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253112) as to what *disputed* really means (i.e. not all that much).

Comment: I've read that and understand the difference.  I'm not asking what the difference is here, I'm starting a discussion around this post to ask if others see an answer in there, because honestly I don't.  If others do see an answer in there, I'll curb flagging these kind of answers.

Comment: I think your flag was correct, personally, but some reviewers in the low quality queue did not agree. That's all, really.

Comment: People upvote garbage and misuse the LQPRQ all the time. I've played volleyball in the H&I queue for hours some nights because some people use [Requires Editing] where they should be using [Unsalvageable].