# Are these questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is the question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005958/how-to-authanticate-connect-sql-server-using-ssl* on topic for Stack Overflow or should it be on Server Fault? The question speaks purely about connecting to an SQL server using SSL and Windows authentication. There is no mention of any programming work involved at all.

Then how about this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006095/latency-on-wired-network-vs-wireless

It's mostly just a listing of [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets, the output of the ping executable. Again no mention of any programming topic what so ever.

Update: Now it can be seen that the first question has been put on hold; as being too broad (rather than for being off topic).

Comment: ***Update:*** Both questions are now closed and will be gone shortly unless redeemed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are (in my opinion) off-topic.

I close-voted the first one as "Too Broad",
The second one as "Off-topic" - *"Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration"*

Comment: Thank you. That's how I voted as well. However both my votes are marked as 'disputed', which I take it means the majority does not agree?

Comment: You appear to have flagged instead of voted (Rep limitation, I think). The review queue can have... "dubious" results.

Comment: Yep, What I did was flagging I thought the terms were used interchangeably here. Guess i will have to be patient till my rep goes up some more (wicked grin)

Comment: *"which I take it means the majority does not agree?"* I'd might be wrong, but as far as I know it needs only one or two reviewers to dispute a flag. So not necessarily the majority.

Comment: @e4c5: This question may contain some more information: [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags).