# Is Disputed state of flags a terminal state?

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I am not sure if this will result into a duplicate. I tried to search it in few ways prior to posting.

I am wondering whether or not the `disputed` state of a flag is a final / terminal state of the flag? Or does it get cleared later as rejected or helpful?

Comment: This question is not exactly a duplicate. It is a direct question on the state of the flag in disputed. I think I know the answer now from the nice explanations provided below. Think the response below will always help others too.

Comment: agree that explanation in accepted answer here is good but I still prefer [one given in duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253117/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flags can only have one of the following three end states:

- helpful: *reviewers agreed with you*
- disputed: *some reviewers disagreed with you*
- declined: *you were plain wrong, don't flag similar posts in the future*

In general, if one of those three states is reached, the reviewing of your flag is complete, its state can not and will not be changed anymore. You'll have to live with the outcome.

A corner case are spam/offensive flags where a moderator can change them to disputed. This is because spam/abusive flags have severe consequences for the OP (-100 reputation and 6 downvotes) and moderators can revert these if the mob flagged wrong.

Comment: There's one slight state change that can occur for spam/offensive flags on posts where a moderator can effectively change their state to "disputed" if needs be. However, that's fairly corner case.

Comment: Is Aged away also a valid state?

Comment: @Ferrybig good point :p

Answer (score 4):

The final state of a flag is one of

- helpful
- declined
- [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag)

There's more information on the difference between declined and disputed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/what-is-the-difference-between-disputed-and-declined-flags).