# Why was my "not an answer" flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116/linking-statically-in-c-sharp/39337#39337):

> As Seb mentioned ILMERGE will do this - but one caveat is that none of the assemblies can contain unsafe code.

It consists of two parts:

1. It says that another answer already is correct.
2. It mentions a little restriction about this answer.

So in my humble opinion this is obviously a comment on that answer. I flagged it and the flag was disputed. Can you explain, please?

---

Edit: gnat suggested this could be a duplicate of [Disputed vs. helpful/declined flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253112/disputed-vs-helpful-declined-flags). I don't think so because I asked not about the difference of flags but about a specific singular flag that has been disputed. Note the difference in the titles - "why" vs. "what".

Comment: according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39337/timeline), three users thought it "looks ok" and probably dismissed your flag that way.

Comment: Disputed == reviewers disagreed. Since I still can't read minds, the answer here is **we don't know nor can we find out with any degree of certainty**.

Comment: However, given the lack of any comments on that answer explaining why it is not an answer, I don't blame the reviewers. Reading just that answer, in isolation, makes me think it is an answer. It doesn't immediately appear to fit our [normal criteria for the NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). I'd decline the flag too.

Comment: But it seems to have been deleted now.

Comment: Given the added context here, I can see how this is a comment on another post. I have converted it to a comment now. Had you put that into a custom mod flag on the post, us moderators could have handled it, bypassing the usual community review queue, this is an exception that qualifies to be handled by us.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. Thanks for making that clear. On the other hand a review normally creates a comment that should make this clear.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: the comment is not always added. It is not added when you flag the post directly, like you did. And even in the review queue, adding the comment is optional, you can opt not do leave one. I'm guessing that the one reviewer that recommended deletion declined to comment.

Comment: @gnat Funny. After reading Pac0's comment about disputed flags not harming my karma I asked myself what's the difference between "disputed" and "declined". And eventually I found the answer you referenced. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters How's that mind reading research coming along? I imagine it'll make moderation easier...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've converted it to a [comment on the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116/linking-statically-in-c-sharp/39147#comment81233600_39147). With your *additional context* you posted in your question here, I can see how it is meant to be a comment there, not an answer to the question.

The community [disputed your flag in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17806514). We can't read reviewer's minds, but I can also see that when handling a pile of reviews, that post doesn't fit the [normal, obvious reasons to use the NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). Had you put your reasoning in a comment on the post when you flagged it would have helped those reviewers make a more informed decision.

Another option would have been to flag the post for moderator attention, with the same motivation. The post is enough of an exception to the NAA norm that asking a moderator to handle this one would have been okay too.

Comment: Well, that was not a fantastic outcome.  It used to be safely buried, now it is a comment on the accepted answer with high visibility.  An incorrect one, unsafe code is just fine.  He probably tried to say "unmanaged code".  Do feel free to just delete it please.

Comment: @HansPassant: heh, since there was only 1 downvote (cast today) on that 'answer' and 4 upvotes, I assumed the community thought it helpful. Also, did I mention the lack of comments on it?

Comment: @HansPassant: perhaps you can reply to the comment explaining how it is wrong? That'd be more valuable than having that same mis-informed opinion re-surface in the future.

Comment: BTW, @OP don't worry, 'disputed' does not in any way harm your 'karma', it does not trigger any kind of punishment by the system. ('declined' is bad to have repeatedly)

Comment: Could you please link directly to the review page instead of linking to the timeline? Since you converted it to a comment, the link to the timeline is now broken.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: done.

Answer (score -16):

It's still a self-contained answer:

> … ILMERGE will do this …

The *"As Seb mentioned"* bit is not the answer itself, but a reference.

Comment: Saying, "Someone else posted an answer that works" is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy no, but saying, "<solution> as per <reference>" has always been an answer.

Comment: No, saying that there is another answer on the same question that works is *not* an answer to the question.  If there was a reference to some external resource, and that reference was used to support an original solution, *then* it would be an answer.  This was merely commentary on another answer.

Comment: I see someone answering here: "As Stephen mentioned 'ILMERGE will do this' is an answer. But as a caveat it actually isn't." :-)

Comment: @Servy: It's a very bad answer, but it is an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, it's not.  It's commentary on another answer.  It was simply a comment posted as an answer because the author couldn't post a comment and wanted to reply to the author of another answer.

Comment: _"ILMERGE will do this"_. Answer. Period.

Comment: @Servy Let me think of this in a different way. Maybe it all happened like this: The question was asked. Then Seb posted a comment. Then Brian posted "As Seb mentioned ..." as an answer. At this point this very answer was likely to be the best answer on this question. But *then* Seb posted his complete answer and deleted his comment. Which made Brians answer look quite inferior. But that's just the way things are, comments become answers, answers become comments. ;-)

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi Considering Brian's answer was posted 2 hours 2 minutes after Seb's answer, we know that wasn't the case.  We also know that didn't happen in this case because comments didn't exist in september of 2008.